# Is there a difference between "throw" and "throw ex"?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

There are some posts that asks what the difference between those two are already. 
(why do I have to even mention this...)

But my question is different in a way that I am calling "throw ex" in another error *god-like* handling method.

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            // something
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            HandleException(ex);
        }
    }

    private static void HandleException(Exception ex) {
        if (ex is ThreadAbortException) {
            // ignore then,
            return;
        }
        if (ex is ArgumentOutOfRangeException) { 
            // Log then,
            throw ex;
        }
        if (ex is InvalidOperationException) {
            // Show message then,
            throw ex;
        }
        // and so on.
    }
}
```

If `try & catch` were used in the `Main`, then I would use `throw;` to rethrow the error.
But in the above simplied code, all exceptions go through `HandleException`

Does `throw ex;` has the same effect as calling `throw` when called inside `HandleException`?

Comment: There is a difference, it has to do with whether or how the stack trace appears in the exception, but I don't remember which is which right now so I won't list this an answer.

Comment: @Joel: Thanks.  I guess using HandleError exception is a bad idea.  I just wanted to refactor some error handling code.

Comment: The third way is to wrap in a new exception and rethrow http://timwise.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/throw-vs-throw-ex-vs-wrap-and-throw-in.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between throw and throw new Exception()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999298/difference-between-throw-and-throw-new-exception)

Answer (score 842, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

- `throw ex` resets the stack trace (so your errors would appear to originate from `HandleException`)
- `throw` doesn't - the original offender would be preserved.

  ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       try
       {
           Method2();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.Write(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   }

   private static void Method2()
   {
       try
       {
           Method1();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           //throw ex resets the stack trace Coming from Method 1 and propogates it to the caller(Main)
           throw ex;
       }
   }

   private static void Method1()
   {
       try
       {
           throw new Exception("Inside Method1");
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           throw;
       }
   }
  ```

Comment: @Scott: Thank you for the link.  And I have also found out about how to extract error handler in the follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730300/how-to-throw-exception-without-resetting-stack-trace/730327#730327

Comment: @Marc : It seems that throw preserves the original offender ONLY if the throw isn't in the method in which the initial exception was thrown (see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152265/what-can-lead-throw-to-reset-a-callstack-im-using-throw-not-throw-ex )

Comment: @Xenan - you aren't the only one - I always get it mixed up too.  It just looks strange.

Comment: If you modify the object referenced by `ex`, for example by setting the `ex.HelpLink` property, this is reflected with both `throw;` and `throw ex;`. If, on the other hand, you assign to the `ex` variable (to make it reference another object), then clearly `throw;` will use the original object, while `throw ex;` will use the new object. It is also interesting to note that even if you use the preferred `throw;` variant, you lose information about the line number inside the `try` block. I just wrote a new answer about that (see also the answer of @Shaul ).

Comment: @Jeppe to be fair the question clearly doesn't show a reassignment to `ex`

Comment: No, you're right. In that case `throw;` and `throw ex;` throw the same object, but its stack trace is modified in different way, as you explain in your answer.

Comment: @Xenan: WYSIWYG - Microsoft Visual Studio editor. And even, I have just experimented throw and throw ex, as its understood by all, throw is the better option as it gives the information from the source of exception. I really wonder why you bring up things which is not necessary. What you see in the output (The real message is what we should be worrying about). I do not understand why do you bring up MSIL part and all here or how it makes sense for optimization.

Comment: I've just read that a benefit of exception filters is that you can avoid unwinding the stack because a catch always unwinds the stack even if you just `throw;` the exception. Is that different from what you are talking about here with preserving the stack trace? When I first read this a couple months ago I thought that is what you meant or they were one in the same.

Comment: @xr280xr not what I was talking about, but an interesting question

Comment: So it is simply the value of the `StackTrace` property that is not preserved but in both cases [https://thomaslevesque.com/2015/06/21/exception-filters-in-c-6/](the stack is unwound). Seems like a strange, and unintuitive design choice for the `StackTrace`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ScottDorman Looks like your link isn't being forwarded correctly after a blog migration. Looks like [it now lives here](https://scottdorman.blog/2007/08/20/difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex-in-net/). **Edit:** Hey, wait, that's _your_ blog! Fix your own links! ;^D

Comment: what could be the use case for using throw ex?

Answer (score 117):

(I posted earlier, and @Marc Gravell has corrected me)

Here's a demonstration of the difference:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    try {
        ThrowException1(); // line 19
    } catch (Exception x) {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception 1:");
        Console.WriteLine(x.StackTrace);
    }
    try {
        ThrowException2(); // line 25
    } catch (Exception x) {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception 2:");
        Console.WriteLine(x.StackTrace);
    }
}

private static void ThrowException1() {
    try {
        DivByZero(); // line 34
    } catch {
        throw; // line 36
    }
}
private static void ThrowException2() {
    try {
        DivByZero(); // line 41
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex; // line 43
    }
}

private static void DivByZero() {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1 / x; // line 49
}
```

and here is the output:

```
Exception 1:
   at UnitTester.Program.DivByZero() in <snip>\Dev\UnitTester\Program.cs:line 49
   at UnitTester.Program.ThrowException1() in <snip>\Dev\UnitTester\Program.cs:line 36
   at UnitTester.Program.TestExceptions() in <snip>\Dev\UnitTester\Program.cs:line 19

Exception 2:
   at UnitTester.Program.ThrowException2() in <snip>\Dev\UnitTester\Program.cs:line 43
   at UnitTester.Program.TestExceptions() in <snip>\Dev\UnitTester\Program.cs:line 25
```

You can see that in Exception 1, the stack trace goes back to the `DivByZero()` method, whereas in Exception 2 it does not.

Take note, though, that the line number shown in `ThrowException1()` and `ThrowException2()` is the line number of the `throw` statement, **not** the line number of the call to `DivByZero()`, which probably makes sense now that I think about it a bit...

#### Output in Release mode

Exception 1:

```
at ConsoleAppBasics.Program.ThrowException1()
at ConsoleAppBasics.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Exception 2:

```
at ConsoleAppBasics.Program.ThrowException2()
at ConsoleAppBasics.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Is it maintains the original stackTrace in debug mode only?

Comment: Its because the compiler's optimization process inlines short methods such as `DevideByZero`, so the stack trace IS the same. maybe you should post this as a question on it`s own

Comment: Original Stack trace in debug mode only. By default, in release mode application tend to the performance optimize. In this optimization process, reduction of the Stack trace, because of in the Stack trace in release mode (production) can potentially expose the sensitive information of the application.

Answer (score 66):

**Throw** preserves the stack trace. So lets say Source1 throws Error1 , its caught by Source2 and Source2 says throw then Source1 Error + Source2 Error will be available in the stack trace.

**Throw ex** does not preserve the stack trace. So all errors of Source1 will be wiped out and only Source2 error will sent to the client.

Sometimes just reading things are not clear , would suggest to watch this video demo to get more clarity , [Throw vs Throw ex in C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGwOd6yMja4).

[image: Throw vs Throw ex]

Answer (score 47):

The other answers are entirely correct, but this answer provides some extra detalis, I think.

Consider this example:

```
using System;

static class Program {
  static void Main() {
    try {
      ThrowTest();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Console.WriteLine("Your stack trace:");
      Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
      Console.WriteLine();
      if (e.InnerException == null) {
        Console.WriteLine("No inner exception.");
      } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Stack trace of your inner exception:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.StackTrace);
      }
    }
  }

  static void ThrowTest() {
    decimal a = 1m;
    decimal b = 0m;
    try {
      Mult(a, b);  // line 34
      Div(a, b);   // line 35
      Mult(b, a);  // line 36
      Div(b, a);   // line 37
    } catch (ArithmeticException arithExc) {
      Console.WriteLine("Handling a {0}.", arithExc.GetType().Name);

      //   uncomment EITHER
      //throw arithExc;
      //   OR
      //throw;
      //   OR
      //throw new Exception("We handled and wrapped your exception", arithExc);
    }
  }

  static void Mult(decimal x, decimal y) {
    decimal.Multiply(x, y);
  }
  static void Div(decimal x, decimal y) {
    decimal.Divide(x, y);
  }
}
```

If you uncomment the `throw arithExc;` line, your output is:

```
Handling a DivideByZeroException.
Your stack trace:
   at Program.ThrowTest() in c:\somepath\Program.cs:line 44
   at Program.Main() in c:\somepath\Program.cs:line 9

No inner exception.
```

Certainly, you have lost information about where that exception happened. If instead you use the `throw;` line, this is what you get:

```
Handling a DivideByZeroException.
Your stack trace:
   at System.Decimal.FCallDivide(Decimal& d1, Decimal& d2)
   at System.Decimal.Divide(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
   at Program.Div(Decimal x, Decimal y) in c:\somepath\Program.cs:line 58
   at Program.ThrowTest() in c:\somepath\Program.cs:line 46
   at Program.Main() in c:\somepath\Program.cs:line 9

No inner exception.
```

This is a lot better, because now you see that it was the `Program.Div` method that caused you problems. But it's still hard to see if this problem comes from line 35 or line 37 in the `try` block.

If you use the third alternative, wrapping in an outer exception, you lose no information:

```
Handling a DivideByZeroException.
Your stack trace:
   at Program.ThrowTest() in c:\somepath\Program.cs:line 48
   at Program.Main() in c:\somepath\Program.cs:line 9

Stack trace of your inner exception:
   at System.Decimal.FCallDivide(Decimal& d1, Decimal& d2)
   at System.Decimal.Divide(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
   at Program.Div(Decimal x, Decimal y) in c:\somepath\Program.cs:line 58
   at Program.ThrowTest() in c:\somepath\Program.cs:line 35
```

In particular you can see that it's **line 35** that leads to the problem. However, this requires people to search the `InnerException`, and it feels somewhat indirect to use inner exceptions in simple cases.

In [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2008/01/02/rethrowing-exceptions-and-preserving-the-full-call-stack-trace.aspx) they preserve the line number (line of the try block) by calling (through reflection) the `internal` intance method `InternalPreserveStackTrace()` on the `Exception` object. But it's not nice to use reflection like that (the .NET Framework might change their `internal` members some day without warning).

Answer (score 11):

When you do `throw ex`, that thrown exception becomes the "original" one. So all previous stack trace will not be there.

If you do `throw`, the exception just goes *down the line* and you'll get the full stack trace.

Answer (score 9):

let's understand the difference between throw and throw ex. I heard that in many .net interviews this common asked is being asked.

Just to give an overview of these two terms, throw and throw ex are both used to understand where the exception has occurred. Throw ex rewrites the stack trace of exception irrespective where actually has been thrown.

Let's understand with an example.

Let's understand first Throw.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    try {
        M1();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(" -----------------Stack Trace Hierarchy -----------------");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(" ---------------- Method Name / Target Site -------------- ");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.TargetSite.ToString());
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void M1() {
    try {
        M2();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw;
    };
}

static void M2() {
    throw new DivideByZeroException();
}
```

output of the above is below.

shows complete hierarchy and method name where actually the exception has thrown.. it is M2 -> M2. along with line numbers

[image]

Secondly.. lets understand by throw ex. Just replace throw with throw ex in M2 method catch block. as below.

[image]

output of throw ex code is as below..

[image]

You can see the difference in the output.. throw ex just ignores all the previous hierarchy and resets stack trace with line/method where throw ex is written.

Answer (score 7):

**Microsoft Docs stands for**:

> Once an exception is thrown, part of the information it carries is the stack trace. The stack trace is a list of the method call hierarchy that starts with the method that throws the exception and ends with the method that catches the exception. If an exception is re-thrown by specifying the exception in the `throw` statement, the stack trace is restarted at the current method and the list of method calls between the original method that threw the exception and the current method is lost. To keep the original stack trace information with the exception, use the `throw` statement without specifying the exception.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2200

Answer (score 6):

No, this will cause the exception to have a different stack trace. Only using a `throw` without any exception object in the `catch` handler will leave the stack trace unchanged.

You may want to return a boolean from HandleException whether the exception shall be rethrown or not.

Answer (score 3):

Look at here: http://blog-mstechnology.blogspot.de/2010/06/throw-vs-throw-ex.html

**Throw**:

```
try 
{
    // do some operation that can fail
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // do some local cleanup
    throw;
}
```

It preserve the Stack information with Exception

This is called as "Rethrow"

If want to throw new exception,

```
throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!");
```

**Throw Ex**:

```
try
{
    // do some operation that can fail
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // do some local cleanup
    throw ex;
}
```

It Won't Send Stack information with Exception

This is called as "Breaking the Stack"

If want to throw new exception,

```
throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!",ex);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use `throw` instead of `throw ex`.

throw ex reset the original stack trace and can't be found the previous stack trace.

If we use throw, we will get a full stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Lucero's answer, here's how you can accomplish the intent of the original code without losing the original stack trace.

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            // something
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (!HandleException(ex)) throw;
        }
    }

    /// <returns>
    ///   true if the exception has been handled;
    ///   false if exception should be passed along
    /// </returns>
    private static bool HandleException(Exception ex) {
        if (ex is ThreadAbortException) {
            // ignore then,
            return true;
        }
        if (ex is ArgumentOutOfRangeException) { 
            // Log then,
            return false;
        }
        if (ex is InvalidOperationException) {
            // Show message then,
            return false;
        }
        // and so on.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To give you a different perspective on this, using throw is particularly useful if you're providing an API to a client and you want to provide verbose stack trace information for your internal library.  By using throw here, I'd get the stack trace in this case of the System.IO.File  library for File.Delete.  If I use throw ex, then that information will not be passed to my handler.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {            
   Method1();            
}

static void Method1() {
    try {
        Method2();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in Method1");             
    }
}

static void Method2() {
    try {
        Method3();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in Method2");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.TargetSite);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().ToString());
    }
}

static void Method3() {
    Method4();
}

static void Method4() {
    try {
        System.IO.File.Delete("");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Displays entire stack trace into the .NET 
        // or custom library to Method2() where exception handled
        // If you want to be able to get the most verbose stack trace
        // into the internals of the library you're calling
        throw;                
        // throw ex;
        // Display the stack trace from Method4() to Method2() where exception handled
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int a = 0;
try {
    int x = 4;
    int y ;
    try {
        y = x / a;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("inner ex");
        //throw;   // Line 1
        //throw e;   // Line 2
        //throw new Exception("devide by 0");  // Line 3
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

1. if all Line 1 ,2 and 3 are commented - 
   Output - inner ex
2. if all Line 2 and 3 are commented - 
   Output - inner ex
       System.DevideByZeroException: {"Attempted to divide by zero."}---------
3. if all Line 1 and 2 are commented - 
   Output - inner ex
       System.Exception: devide by 0 ----
4. if all Line 1 and 3 are commented - 
   Output - inner ex
       System.DevideByZeroException: {"Attempted to divide by zero."}---------

and StackTrace will be reset in case of throw ex;