# application stop unexpectedly

Tags: c#, windows

Why did my application stop unexpectedly? I tried everything to solve the error but I can not find the solution. This is a Windows application.

UPDATE:

event viewer:

1

```
Faulting application viamura.crawlerapp.exe, version 1.0.0.0, stamp 4d9d9be8, faulting module imon.dll, version 2.70.16.0, stamp 455c9b06, debug? 0, fault address 0x0002474a.
```

2

```
Application: ViaMura.CrawlerApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods+OSSOCK.recv(IntPtr, Byte*, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags, System.Net.Sockets.SocketError ByRef)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.ReadSingleByte()
   at System.Net.StreamChunkBytes.get_NextByte()
   at System.Net.ChunkParse.GetChunkSize(System.Net.IReadChunkBytes, Int32 ByRef)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.ProcessReadChunkedSize(System.Net.StreamChunkBytes)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.ReadChunkedCallbackWorker(System.Net.NestedSingleAsyncResult, System.Net.ConnectStream)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.ReadChunkedCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()


For more information, see Help and Support Center at
```

3

```
EventType clr20r3, P1 viamura.crawlerapp.exe, P2 1.0.0.0, P3 4d9d9759, P4 viamura.crawlerapp, P5 1.0.0.0, P6 4d9d9759, P7 e, P8 36, P9 system.exception, P10 NIL.
```

code 1:

```
try
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new CrawlerApp());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogError.WriteError("Napaka: " + e.Message);
                LogError.WriteError("StackTrace: " + e.StackTrace);
            }
```

code 2:

```
#region

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WebCrawler.Core.DataInterfaces;
using WebCrawler.Core.Entities;
using WebCrawler.Data;
using WebCrawler.Lib;
using WebCrawler.Logic;

#endregion

namespace ViaMura.CrawlerApp
{
    public delegate void WebSiteVisitedCallback(WebSiteVisitedEventArgs args);

    public partial class CrawlerApp : Form
    {
        #region Properties

        private IDaoFactory _daoFactory;
        private IList<Agencies> agencies;
        private Agencies agency;
        private CrawlerManager manager;

        private IDaoFactory DaoFactory
        {
            get
            {
                if (_daoFactory == null)
                {
                    _daoFactory = new NHibernateDaoFactory(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NHibernateConfigPath"]);
                    return _daoFactory;
                }
                else
                    return _daoFactory;
            }
        }

        private string ConnectionString
        {
            get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        //static uint LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE = 0x00000002;
        //static uint LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE = 0x00000040;
        //static uint LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH = 0x00000008;

        public CrawlerApp()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();
            //LoadDLL();         
            Init();            
            LoadAgenciesData();            
        }

        /*[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string dllFilePath, IntPtr hFile, uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr dllPointer);

        private IntPtr LoadWin32Library(string dllFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                IntPtr moduleHandle = LoadLibraryEx(dllFilePath, IntPtr.Zero, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);
                if (moduleHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    // I'm gettin last dll error
                    int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new ApplicationException(
                        string.Format("There was an error during dll loading : {0}, error - {1}", dllFilePath, errorCode)
                        );
                }

                return moduleHandle;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Couldn't load library {0}{1}{2}", dllFilePath, Environment.NewLine, exc.Message), exc);
            }
        }*/

        private void Init()
        {
            manager = new CrawlerManager(DaoFactory, ConnectionString);
            manager.OnWebSiteVisited += manager_OnWebSiteVisited;

            timerSetTime.Start();
        }

        /*private void LoadDLL()
        {
            string XulRunnerPath = @"D:\PROJEKTI\crawler\WebCrawlerSuite\NCrawler\GeckoEngine\xulRunner";
            //string XulRunnerPath = @"D:\Development\Own\ViaMura\WebCrawlerSuite\NCrawler\GeckoEngine\xulRunner";

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(XulRunnerPath, "*.dll");
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                LoadWin32Library(file);
            }
        }*/

        private void LoadAgenciesData()
        {
            agencies = DaoFactory.GetAgenciesDao().GetAll();
            agencies = agencies.OrderBy(a => a.LoadCrawlerDate).ToList(); //TODO performance OrderBy
        }

        private void timerSetTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblCurrentTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            foreach (var tmpAgency in agencies)
            {
                if (!tmpAgency.Active || bwCrawler.IsBusy) continue;

                DateTime? crawlerTime;
                if (tmpAgency.LoadCrawlerDate != null)
                {
                    crawlerTime = ((DateTime) tmpAgency.LoadCrawlerDate).AddMinutes(tmpAgency.CrawlerDelayInMinutes);
                }
                else
                    crawlerTime = null;

                if (crawlerTime == null || DateTime.Now > crawlerTime)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        txtStatus.Text = "Start crawler: " + tmpAgency.Name + " " + DateTime.Now + " " + txtStatus.Text + Environment.NewLine + txtStatus.Text;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        txtStatus.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
                    }

                    if (tmpAgency.LoadCrawlerDate != null)
                    {
                        tmpAgency.LoadCrawlerDate = ((DateTime) tmpAgency.LoadCrawlerDate).AddDays(1);
                    }
                    else
                        tmpAgency.LoadCrawlerDate = null;

                    agency = tmpAgency;
                    bwCrawler.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
            }
        }

        private void manager_OnWebSiteVisited(object source, WebSiteVisitedEventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                txtStatus.Invoke(new WebSiteVisitedCallback(WebSiteVisited), new object[] { args });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void WebSiteVisited(WebSiteVisitedEventArgs args)
        {
            txtStatus.Text = args.Status + " " + args.VisitedUrl + Environment.NewLine + txtStatus.Text;

            if (args.Status)
            {
                lblNumberOfMatches.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(lblNumberOfMatches.Text) + 1).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblNumberOfFailures.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(lblNumberOfFailures.Text) + 1).ToString();
            }

            if (txtStatus.Text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length > 200)
            {
                txtStatus.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        private void bwCrawler_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            manager.ExtractDataFromAgency(agency);
        }

        private void bwCrawler_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtStatus.Text = Environment.NewLine + "End and Saved last CrawledDate: " + DateTime.Now +
                             Environment.NewLine + txtStatus.Text;

            try
            {
                IAgenciesDao aDao = DaoFactory.GetAgenciesDao();

                agency = aDao.GetById(agency.idAgencies, false);
                agency.LoadCrawlerDate = DateTime.Now;

                aDao.SaveOrUpdate(agency);
                aDao.CommitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txtStatus.Text = ex.Message;
            }

            LoadAgenciesData();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: We need more information - what is it doing when it crashes? What have you already tried? What happens if you use the debugger and step through it? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Where's your main method

Comment: application just close, no error nothing. Try to catch excpetion if is one... It stops after an hour of working not right away...

Comment: Did you look at the Event Log?

Comment: Memory is getting corrupted.  Unmanaged code is invariably the cause, there are plenty of traces of it in your code.  Very hard to debug, you usually have to do something drastical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running NOD32 anti-virus? If so, Google suggests that could be the problem:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/93618/net-remoting-throws-system-accessviolationexception-when-closing-client

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxremoting/thread/bc72660e-d60d-4b05-b217-d563a12cb8c1/

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30803254/accessviolationexception-from-ossockrecv-when-using-webrequest.aspx

http://www.ureader.com/msg/1434893.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add additional parameterless catch:

```
catch (Exception e)            
{
    LogError.WriteError("Napaka: " + e.Message);
    LogError.WriteError("StackTrace: " + e.StackTrace);
}
catch
{
    LogError.WriteError("Untyped Exception");
}
```

In some cases exceptions are not of .net Exception type.
Though this issue is specific to CLR 1.1: [Throwing Exceptions That Are Not Exceptions](http://www.jasonbock.net/jb/Default.aspx?blog=entry.9d6dbbd00d294f6fa2fee35f03e56ae8)

See also discussion at [Catch Exception treatment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655430/catch-exception-treatment)

Additional [link](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/22287-General-Catch-Handler-C.aspx): "If the program uses libraries written in other languages, then there may be an exception that is not derived from the class Exception. Such exceptions can be handled by the parameter-less catch statement."