# How can I prevent 'System.AccessViolationException' when making a client side WCF call?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am running a Windows Service which is making several calls to multiple other WCF services running elsewhere. Sometimes our clients encounter an uncatchable exception when calling to an endpoint which brings down our service. The server side of the endpoint is running an instance which, aside from the database calls it makes, is completely stateless.

The exception is 'System.AccessViolationException' which I am aware falls under the category of corrupted state exceptions, as I have read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx#id0070035).

I am aware of the [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions] attribute, and all of the warnings against using it to handle code that is not also maintained by the catcher of the exception.

The top of the call stack delves into the native windows libraries that WCF wraps:

```
    System.AccessViolationException Stack: 
  at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods+OSSOCK.recv(IntPtr, Byte*, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags) 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags, System.Net.Sockets.SocketError ByRef) 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags) 
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32) 
  at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32) 
  at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(System.Net.HttpWebRequest, Boolean, Boolean) 
  at System.Net.Connection.PollAndRead(System.Net.HttpWebRequest, Boolean) 
  at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean) 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndSubmitRequest() 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetRequestSubmitDone(System.Net.ConnectStream) 
  at System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartRequest(Boolean, System.Net.HttpWebRequest, System.Net.TriState) 
  at System.Net.Connection.SubmitRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest, Boolean) 
  at System.Net.ServicePoint.SubmitRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest, System.String) 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(System.Net.ServicePoint) 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(System.Net.TransportContext ByRef) 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput+WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream() 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(System.TimeSpan) 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1+HttpRequestChannel+HttpChannelRequest[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SendRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message, System.TimeSpan) 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message, System.TimeSpan) 
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message, System.TimeSpan) 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(System.String, Boolean, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime, System.Object[], System.Object[], System.TimeSpan) 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime) 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData ByRef, Int32) 
  at WCFCommunicator.IComEndpoint.TestEndpoint() 
  at WCFCommunicator.SendingLayer+<>c.<VerifyCurrentEndpoints>b__38_0(WCFCommunicator.IComEndpoint) 
  at WCFCommunicator.HttpWrapper.Client`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].UseCom[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Func`2<System.__Canon,Boolean>, ErrorType ByRef, System.String) 
  at WCFCommunicator.SendingLayer.VerifyCurrentEndpoints() 
  at WCFCommunicator.LocalSubscriptionAnalyzer.ValidateEndpoints_Elapsed(System.Object, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) 
  at System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(System.Object) 
  at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(System.Object) 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) 
  at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback() at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire() at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers() 
  at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback()
```

The client code is always passed in as a lambda and executed in a try/catch/finally which looks like:

```
public TReturn UseCom<TReturn>(Func<Com, TReturn> code)
{
    Com channel = cFactory.CreateChannel();
    bool error = true;
    try
    {
        TReturn result = code(channel);
        ((IClientChannel)channel).Close();
        error = false;
        return result;
    }
    catch (EndpointNotFoundException e)
    {
        //log and handle
        return default(TReturn);
    }
    catch (FaultException e)
    {
        //log and handle
        return default(TReturn);
    }
    catch (CommunicationException e)
    {
        //log and handle
        return default(TReturn);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //log and handle
        return default(TReturn);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (error)
        {
            ((IClientChannel)channel).Abort();                    
        }                
    }
}
```

Which is used like:

```
var result = clientInstance.UseCom(endpoint => endpoint.TestEndpoint());
```

This issue has been EXTREMELY hard to reproduce and does not seem to show any other patterns, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something is going wrong elsewhere in your stack, there is insufficient detail in your question to determine what, exactly. But what is the `Com` type?

Comment: Com is the interface that the endpoint is using. I have updated my original post with the entire callstack, and an example of how the function is invoked.

Comment: What A/V solution are you running?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584253/application-stop-unexpectedly

Might also be useful be post the Windows Event Viewer stack trace. I've personally had similar issues wit A/V solutions (Kaspersky a Nod32) doing something very similar, so maybe you can focus outside your application and look at the environment?

Comment: There is no AV running on this particular box, the boxes are running on a very locked down self-contained network. The windows event viewer stack trace is the trace posted in the original post.

Comment: Just in case, did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm seeing something very similar in System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() with a similar lambda-based call...

Comment: I never found a true solution. We updated all of our customers to .net 4.6.2 and the problem seemed to go away on its own after that.