# The SMTP server requires a secure connection when i try to send an email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Hi guys I create a mail class to send emails.

```
public void SendEmail(string subject, string messageBody, string toAddress)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.To.Add(toAddress);
    //mail.To.Add("amit_jain_online@yahoo.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("noreply3ncra@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = subject;
    string Body = messageBody;
    mail.Body = Body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
         ("noreply3ncra@gmail.com", "********");
    //Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

But I got this error:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

So I have to sign into **Gmail** and enter the **captcha** code and after this every thing is going to be ok.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

You should enable application to access gmail account.

**Try this link:**

[Gmail allow access](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

**For more info refer this link:**

[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not)

Comment: this question is asked every time when i got this error.

Comment: Try this link for more inormation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not

Answer (score 2):

**Add this also:**

Add port no also to your code as:

```
 smtp.Port = 587;
```

For more info refer this link:

[Codeproject link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/644799/The-SMTP-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-th)