# Send email using c# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated

Tags: c#

I was create sample email sender using c# but it shows an error is:

> *The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication
>   Required.*

```
private void SendHtmlFormattedEmail(string recepientEmail, string subject, string body)
{
    using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
    {
       mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("sysumurugan@gmail.com");
       mailMessage.Subject = subject;
       mailMessage.Body = body;
       mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(recepientEmail));
       SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
       smtp.EnableSsl = true;
       smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
       System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sysumurugan@gmail.com", "XXXXXXXXX");
       smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
       smtp.Timeout = 10000;
       smtp.Send(mailMessage);
    }
}
```

please help me for sample mail sender code

Status:System.Net.Mail.SmtpStatusCode.MustIssueStartTlsFirst

Comment: Credentials you provide in `NetworkCred` will be ignored if `UseDefaultCredentials` is `true`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Try swapping these lines like so:

```
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new    System.Net.NetworkCredential("sysumurugan@gmail.com", "XXXXXXXXX");
```

Comment: I swap these lines and run, but still It show same error.

Comment: This question has been answered previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not

Answer (score 1):

I went to the following link:
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

and turned on the option *Access for less secure apps*

[image]