# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.?8

Tags: c#, email, authentication

I was create sample email sender using c# but it shows an error is:

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

```
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add("toAddress@gmail.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("fromAddress@gmail.com", "Test Mail !", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
        mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.Body = "Test message";
        mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myMail@gmail.com", "password");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.Send(mail);
```

Web config:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="myMail@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" password="password"
          port="587" userName="myMail@gmail.com" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Enable less secure apps. This is a security issue by google for gmail. Check my answer

Comment: Does your Google account have two-factor authentication enabled? If so, you can generate an unique app password which you would use instead of your normal password.

Comment: @Reshma See this article by Google: [**Sign in using App Passwords**](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gmail Error :The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not)

Answer (score 1):

If you have two-factor authentication enabled, you will need to generate yourself an App Password for your Google account.

The steps for generating such password are as follows ( [[Google page]](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) | [[Archived page]](http://web.archive.org/web/20150316103559/https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)):

> 1. Visit your [App passwords](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) page. You may be asked to sign in to your Google Account.
> 2. At the bottom, click Select app and choose the app you’re using.
> 3. Click Select device and choose the device you’re using.
>
> [image]
>
> 4. Click Generate.
> 5. Follow the instructions to enter the App password (the 16 character code in the yellow bar) on your device.
>
> [image]
>
> 6. Click Done.
>
> Once you click done, you’ll won’t see that App password code again.
>   However, you will see a list of apps and devices you’ve created App
>   passwords for.

Then, in your NetworkCredentials, replace your password with the generated 16-digit passcode.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the mail by code and when you receive the error, login to your gmail account and check the inbox after 2 or 3 mins. You will receive a mail like this :

```
#;
#;
```

[image]

```
#;
#;
```

[image]