# Send email from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email, gmail

im trying to send email from vb.net get error msg .... "The SMTP" server require scour connection or the client was not authenticated"

```
Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("ejazsarwar110@gmail.com", "*******")
Smtp_Server.Port = 587
Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

e_mail = New MailMessage()
e_mail.From = New MailAddress("ejazsarwar110@gmail.com", "Ejaz Sarwar")
e_mail.To.Add("ajaz661@yahoo.com")
e_mail.Subject = "Email Sending"
e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
e_mail.Body = txtSunCovered.Text
Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
MsgBox("Mail Sent")
```

Comment: @jmcilhinney for advise ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.?8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074463/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated)