# Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection... The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Tags: email, powershell, smtp

Alright so as the title says, I get this error when trying to send email via PowerShell:

*Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.*

I have looked at numerous questions related to the same issue. But I can't seem to make my script work:

```
    #Email alerts when a user gets locked out
##############################################################################
$pass = Get-Content .\securepass.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$name = "sender@gmail.com"
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($name,$pass)
##############################################################################
$From = "sender@gmail.com"
$To = "recipient@domain.org"
$Subject = "User Locked Out"
$Body = "A user has been locked out of his/her account."
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"

Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject `
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort `
-Credential $cred -UseSsl
##############################################################################
```

I have logged into the Gmail account from the machine that will be running the script. I have also enabled *Access for less secure apps* from the Google account manager. I do get this to work just fine if I prompt for the credentials using the `-Credential (Get-Credential)` instead of calling for the `$cred` variable.

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: If you need to be authenticated with the SMTP server, do you need to send along SMTP user credentials?

Comment: @EvanFrisch He's doing that (`-Credential $cred`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I am definitely going blind, my bad.

Comment: If authentication works when supplying the password via `Get-Credential`, but not when reading the password from a file, the problem is most likely with the password file. Double-check the file's content (trailing whitespace, encoding, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, You got me to look at the right area. I figured it out. The password file contained the password already encrypted. I replaced it with the plaintext unencrypted password so it gets encrypted when setting my $pass variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail Error :The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not)

Answer (score 2):

If the file contains the encrypted password it's better to read it like this (without the parameters `-AsPlainText` and `-Force`):

```psh
$pass = Get-Content .\securepass.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
```

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $sec = 'foobar' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
PS C:\> $sec
System.Security.SecureString
PS C:\> $txt = $sec | ConvertFrom-SecureString
PS C:\> $txt
01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000615ce070639b9647a5e05d42b41d373
0000000000200000000001066000000010000200000001614c19281e7c0b076cceb38e284b0f18b
c0d813ea40ed055dde96fd9ccb6977000000000e8000000002000020000000a10c7019eb224c3c6
387ba03bcd94993a50e0c468248284bbce4d235b11f1b94100000002421a5d7102de13c46ccc1db
c4921287400000000412332ecb500828f4403f3e225089c629369744bad62609b528ed0a7318abf
512c9b6a8884c43b3adc8a13d5d21a9ed27e56702bcc7db094da9d9d4c02dfa74
PS C:\> $sec2 = $txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
PS C:\> $sec2
System.Security.SecureString
PS C:\> $cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential 'foo', $sec2
PS C:\> $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
foobar
```

Beware though that encryption of secure strings is tied to the user and host encrypting them, meaning you can't decrypt a secure string on another host or as another user.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer after looking at my passwords file content, thanks to Angsgar. The securepass.txt had the encrypted contents inside, not plaintext. What I did was replace it with the actual password that will then be encrypted when setting my $pass variable. All is good now!

Answer (score 0):

Ansgar's answer is a good generic answer, but for Google, they have multiple SMTP servers that you can use.  `smtp.google.com` requires authentication, but not all of them do.

From [Google's doc](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en), if your site is a G Suite site and you will always be sending from a specific IP address, you can specify the address in G Suite configuration and then use the G Suite SMTP relay at `smtp-relay.gmail.com`.  This is only available to G Suite users, and requires either authentication or a static IP.  At our site, we have an internal SMTP server that we use for these sorts of emails which relays to Google's G Suite SMTP relay server.

If you are sending email only to Google or G Suite addresses, you can specify `aspmx.l.google.com` as your SMTP address.  This is known as the restricted Gmail SMTP server.