# I am getting an error trying to send email from the Powershell command prompt

Tags: powershell, email, command-line

I am using this link "https://www.howtogeek.com/120011/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-send-email-from-the-command-line-in-windows-without-extra-software/" to send an email from Powershell.  I use these commands:

```
$EmailFrom = "ferrad@gmail.com"
$EmailTo = "ferrad@gmail.com"
$Subject = "Test from CMD"
$Body = "Hello world"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $false;
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

All the above commands appear to execute fine except the last, where I get this response:

```
Exception calling "Send" with "4" argument(s): "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication
Required. For more information, go to"
At line:1 char:1
+ $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
```

What extra commands to I need to add to this script to fix this problem?

Comment: See [Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection... The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30789299/1701026) or as you using the .net method [Gmail Error :The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20906077/1701026)

Comment: SEE the following :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503333/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67950293/how-to-fix-gmail-smtp-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-th

Comment: Are you on a corporate network?  Inside a corporate network port forwarding is used and all port 587 will go to internal mail server (not gmail).  So you will never be able to connect to gmail inside your company firewall.

Comment: @jdweng no, I'm at home on my normal home network

Comment: Can you logon to the SMTP gamil server through another application?  There may be something wrong with the account.  The FROM address and the Credentials has to be from same account.  If you still have issues see https://mailmeteor.com/blog/gmail-smtp-settings