# SMTP Mail with ASP.net Error 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, smtp

Good day,  I'm a beginner from using ASP.net and SMTP Mailer

Heres my Question, I always encounter this Error when i send email from my local
and searched and tried the solutions around the net but not so lucky,
I hope someone point out what codes do i need and where i encounter this errror

```
Message = "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at"
```

Heres my Code:

```
protected void btnSendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer is obsolete in 2.0
            // System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient is the alternate class for this in 2.0
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

            try
            {
                MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Value, txtName.Value);
                smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myUser@gmail", "password");
                // You can specify the host name or ipaddress of your server
                // Default in IIS will be localhost 
                smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                //Default port will be 25
                smtpClient.Port = 25;
                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                //From address will be given as a MailAddress Object
                message.From = fromAddress;

                // To address collection of MailAddress
                message.To.Add("myEmail@gmail.com");
                message.Subject = txtSubject.Value;

                // CC and BCC optional
                // MailAddressCollection class is used to send the email to various users
                // You can specify Address as new MailAddress("admin1@yoursite.com")
                message.CC.Add("myEmail@gmail.com");

                // You can specify Address directly as string
                message.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("myEmail@gmail.com"));

                //Body can be Html or text format
                //Specify true if it  is html message
                message.IsBodyHtml = false;

                // Message body content
                message.Body = txtaMessage.Value;
                message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                message.HeadersEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                // Send SMTP mail
                smtpClient.Send(message);

                lblSuccess.Text = "Email successfully sent.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblSuccess.Text = "Send Email Failed.";
            }
        }
```

Comment: try to add `smtp.UserDefaultCreadential = true` and chage port to 587

Comment: @kulotskie tried that after reading this, still not working, same error shows

Comment: could you specify what is the error ??

Comment: @kulotskie `The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this reference [ASP Simple SMTP for C# and VB](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-HTML-Page-File-as-Email-Body-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) it helps me a lot for may smtp problem

Comment: didnt work, the approach must be too old to work on an Entity Framework 4.0

Comment: Im using VS2015 and im using that code and its work 100%

Comment: baka sa email mo na mismong gamit yan kc sakin nag wowork naman sya ee

Comment: ASP kasi ung code ko eh, di ko alam kung same approach lang ba sila sa pagcall

Comment: sorry mali C# codes po yan ung ginamit na pang design is ASP and mark up lang po si asp more on design lang tlga

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86849/discussion-between-enrique-gil-and-kulotskie).

Comment: di parin gumana still the same error parin ang lumabas `The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at`

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86849/discussion-between-enrique-gil-and-kulotskie pasko ka bilis

Comment: paUP nalang din ng sagot ko aa salamat :3

Answer (score 2):

i tried to make a simple codes for sending email try this

`MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
            mm.From = new MailAddress("fromEmail");
            mm.To.Add("toEmail");
            mm.CC.Add("ccEmail");
            mm.Subject = "StringSubject";
            mm.Body = "BodySubject";
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            NetworkCred.UserName = "UsernameString";
            NetworkCred.Password = "PasswordString";
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            try
            {
                smtp.Send(mm);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }`

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look on google support team, what they are saying regarding sending mail from application.
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en

Also following link can help you.

[Gmail Error :The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not)

Comment: @enrique Gil May gmail preventing you from sending email.

Comment: Thanks sir! Yes, I am prevented by Gmail because the Allow Less Secure Apps is not Turned on!! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Goto Account of Gmail , then select 
Connected apps & sites
Allow less secure apps: ON(if this is off you cannot send mails through apps,or your websites )