# Sending E-mail to Gmail account using VB.net 2010

Tags: sendmail, vb.net-2010

I have a problem trying to make the user of my program send an Email to my Gmail account, this my Setup:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class Form1
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles txtBody.TextChanged
    lblCharCount.Text = String.Format("Letter Count: {0}", txtBody.Text.Length)
End Sub

Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    If YourEmailTextBox.Text <> "" AndAlso txtBody.Text <> "" Then
        Dim message As New MailMessage
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
        message.To.Add(YourEmailTextBox.Text.Trim())
        message.From = New MailAddress(YourEmailTextBox.Text, "heading")
        message.Subject = txtSubject.Text
        message.Body = txtBody.Text
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        smtp.Port = "587"
        smtp.EnableSsl = True
        smtp.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("MyGmailAccount@gmail.com", "MyPassword")
        Try
            smtp.Send(message)
            MsgBox("your message has been sent")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    Else
        MsgBox("Please enter a message into the body and the email address of the recipient", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

And this is the problem :

[image]

Some help Please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see what's behind your error box, but you're probably not setting the smtp.Credentials correctly. Here's an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20546/How-to-Send-Mails-from-your-GMAIL-Account-through

Also see: [Gmail Error :The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not)

Comment: I tried them all.... nothing work.
I believe that problem not in the code.
Something goes wrong and i don't  know what it could be.[EAnders](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5179009/eanders)

Comment: Google send me a "Sign-in attempt prevented", i don't know what's happening

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not

Comment: Yes, it's work, thanks a lot[EAnders](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5179009/eanders)