# Use powershell to send email while saving your password securely in encrypted file

Tags: powershell, email, security, smtp

I have found similar threads but none that solve my issue. I am trying to send an email using SMTP server, with attachment (via gmail). That's the easy bit done. The main error response I get is

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required."

I think it has to do with getting the password from the password file into the Credentials

```
"Password123" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "C:\Folder\Password.txt"
$EmailFrom = "emailaddress@gmail.com"
$EmailTo = "otheremailaddress@gmail.com" 
$Subject = "Log file from server" 
$Subject = "Subject" 
$Body = "Here is the log file from the server" 
$File = "C:\Folder\LogFile.txt"
$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($File,'text/plain')

$mailmessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage
$mailmessage.from = ($EmailFrom)
$mailmessage.To.add($emailto)
$mailmessage.Subject = $Subject
$mailmessage.Body = $Body
$mailmessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)

$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 

$username = "emailaddress@gmail.com"
$pass = Get-Content "C:\Folder\Password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $pass);

$SMTPClient.Send($mailmessage)
```

I want to remove the first line of this code as it's never a good idea to have a password in the script.

If I change the password variable to the following I have no issue

```
$pass = "Password123"
```

All the other forum posts I found have suggested things haven't solved my problem.

Also changing gmails settings to allow access from less secure apps doesn't solve my problem.

Any help would greatly be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

1. I have gmail accessible for less secure apps
2. I have 2 step verification off for gmail
3. I believe the issue is reading the password file. It's a case of not being able to accept password from the file when it is encrypted. I tried it with an un-encrypted password but that isn't much better for scripting

Comment: Put the first line in a separate script, and then run it once, from the security context of the user that needs to run the email script (either as a scheduled task or by logging in as that user). Now the rest should work

Comment: That produces the same result as before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail Error :The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not)

Comment: Is your code meant to run on your personal machine, work machine, or run also by other people?

Comment: It's meant to run on the server machine but I haven't got it working on my machine yet. I'll try and fix the duplicate error but it works when I put the password in the script without any encryption

Comment: Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into issues with this in the past - I think one of the common gotcha's was already mentioned by Mathias - watch out for running under different credentials (running as a schedule job) since decoding depends on using the user's session information. The one thing I'm not quite sure about in your example is why you're doing a subsequent convert to plain text- otherwise though, the below should take your username and password, export it to a file, then import it in as a credential you can use later.

```
$user = "UsernameGoesHere"
$passwordtostore = 'PasswordGoesHere'
$secureStringPWD = $passwordtostore | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$secureStringText = $secureStringPWD | ConvertFrom-SecureString
Set-Content "C:\temp\authenticationfile.cfg" $secureStringText
# Retrieve password
$pwdin = Get-Content "C:\temp\authenticationfile.cfg"
$password = $pwdin | ConvertTo-SecureString
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user,$password
```

Hope that helps?