# Gmail Error : System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, gmail

Here is related topic similar to my problem & the answer is correct :

[gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not)

And here is related site :

[send-email-from-gmail-with-smtp-authentication-but-got-5_5_1-authentication-required-error](https://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1546/send-email-from-gmail-with-smtp-authentication-but-got-5_5_1-authentication-required-error.aspx)

I used c# to send mail & my code is correct & works on local & old host.
The problem is about new host that i don't have **REMOTE** access.
In the new host i got this email from google :
[image: google mail]
I clicked on `Check activity` & click `it was me`.
But problem still exists.
I don't have remote access to the new host & i do n't want give my password to them.
Here is the error from new host :

> sending email was failed, SmtpException -> Error :
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure
>   connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response
>   was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at at
>   System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode,
>   String response) at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection
>   conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender,
>   MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean
>   allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at
>   Virtual_Visa_Cards.WebForm4.Send_Email_Gmail(String display_name,
>   String from, String to, String subject, String html_body, String
>   sender_email, String sender_password)

What is the solution & how can i add new host ip as trusted in gmail account?(Please conside on my edits)

**Edit :**
1. I do n't want to enable two factor authentication
2. Low secure apps is On
3.

> But what if you don't have access to the production server. try the
>   solution 3
>
> solution 3 for case 3: You have to enable login from other timezone /
>   ip for your google account.
>
> to do this follow the link https://g.co/allowaccess and allow access
>   by clicking the continue button.
>
> And that's it. Here you go. Now you will be able to login from any of
>   the computer and by any means of app to your google account.

When i use the link in solution 3 email can be send for 1-5 times.
After that error appears again & i should use the [link](https://g.co/allowaccess) again.

Comment: Thanks! For me after allowing access via this link  https://g.co/allowaccess it finally worked & the email was sent successfully.