# Sending email using google smtp server will return this error "The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required"

Tags: iis, smtp, asp.net-core-mvc, gmail

I have the following code inside my asp.net core MVC  web application, to send an email using google smtp server:-

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("info@***.com");
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("info@**.com"));
mail.Subject = "New Submission from Web Site";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
System.Text.StringBuilder mailBody = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
mailBody.AppendLine("<b>Dear Sirs, </b><br/><br/>");
mailBody.AppendLine(
"New Submission has been submitted from Web site. To view the new submission please click on the link <a href'https://*****/Submissions/details/" + sc.Submission.Id.ToString()
 + " <br/> <span style='font-weight:bold'>Regards</span> <br/> <span style='font-weight:bold'>Web Site</span>"
);
                
mail.Body = mailBody.ToString();
// Create a new Smpt Client using Google's servers
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtpClient.Port = 587;


string smtpConn = configuration.GetSection("SMTP").GetSection("pass").Value;

smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
("info@****.com", smtpConn); // ***use valid credentials***

smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

but i got this error:-

> SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at

any idea? although i am running the application from a machine where i can login to the gmail account from it...

Comment: Make sure the  user has less secure apps enabled,  also check that they have 2fa disabled on their account.   If its still not working you may have to add https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol

Answer (score 4):

> SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the
> client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0
> Authentication Required. Learn more at

When you encounter this error, it may be caused by the following situations

1. **Wrong password**, solution: just enter the correct password.
2. **When you try to log in from some App**.

   Solution: Go to the security settings of [this link](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps), and enable less secure apps.
3. **This usually happens when you try to log in from another time zone or IP address computer**. The production server and the email ID you use are in different time zones.

   There are **two solutions** for this situation:

   - Log in to production server via remote access, and sign in to
     gmail once with your credentials. They will ask for the confirmation,
     confirm it and log out.
   - Or log in gmail to your local computer, Follow [this Link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1144110?hl=en) and
     choose [review this activity](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity) and take proper actions.

**If you do not have access to the production server,** then try:

You have to enable login from other timezone/ip for your google account.

to do this follow the link https://g.co/allowaccess and allow access by clicking the continue button.

More details, you could refer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not).

Comment: the g.co/allowacess link did it for me after seeing the same suggestions in 20 different articles.