# Gmail SMTP clien fails on Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, smtpclient

When I send mail from local it works pretty well, but when I deploy on azure it fails.

Error: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at

[image]

Comment: does you azure web app have TLS/SSL?

Comment: The TLS version has to be TLS 1.2 or 1.3.  See : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azuretls12/  What version of Net are you using?  What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10 and .net core 2.2

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens when you try login from different time zone or IP Address Computer. Your production server and the mail id you have used both are in different time zone. Choose either of these two solutions:

- Log in to production server via remote access, and sign in to gmail once with your credentials. They will ask for the confirmation, confirm it and log out. (*If you are using a VM*)

  OR
- log in gmail to your local computer, Follow this [Link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1144110?hl=en) and choose [review this activity](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity) and take proper actions.

Check out this **SO question** to know more (additionally you can verify **Roshan Parmar**'s points from this): [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not#:~:text=solution%20for%20case%201%3A%20Enter,to%20login%20from%20all%20apps.&text=Use%20that%20newly%20generated%20password%20to%20authenticate%20via%20SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not#:%7E:text=solution%20for%20case%201%3A%20Enter,to%20login%20from%20all%20apps.&text=Use%20that%20newly%20generated%20password%20to%20authenticate%20via%20SMTP).

Comment: Does this help you?