# Why does SQL Server Developer database mail not send mail after proper configuration?

Tags: sql-server, database, email

I have set up various emails (Outlook and Gmail) with proper SMTP settings, yet database mail will not work.

The mail is stuck in the queue.

How do I get the mail to function?

Set up Outlook, then Gmail accounts to use, but neither worked.

I got this error:

> "Date     2/22/2023 7:58:37 AM
> Log       Database Mail (Database Mail Log)
>
> Log ID        1057
> Process ID        8752
> Mail Item ID  19
> Last Modified 2/22/2023 7:58:37 AM
> Last Modified By  sa
>
> Message
> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 2 (2023-02-22T07:58:37).
>
> Exception Message:
>
> Exception Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.MailFramework.Exceptions.BaseMailFrameworkException
>
> Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at)
>
> Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
> TargetSite: Void Send(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.MailFramework.Framework.IMessage)
> HelpLink: NULL
> Source: DatabaseMailProtocols
> HResult: -2146232832
>
> StackTrace information
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.MailFramework.Smtp.SmtpMailSender.Send(IMessage msg)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Controller.ProfileMailSender.SendMailToAccount(Account a, IMessageSender ms, OutMailItem si)
>
> Exception information
>
> Exception Type: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
> StatusCode: MustIssueStartTlsFirst
> Message: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at
> Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
> TargetSite: Void CheckResponse(System.Net.Mail.SmtpStatusCode, System.String)
> HelpLink: NULL
> Source: System
> HResult: -2146233088
>
> StackTrace
>
> at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
> at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.MailFramework.Smtp.SmtpMailSender.Send(IMessage msg).
> )

Comment: GMail stopped allowing basic SMTP authentication years ago without explicit configuration. Last year the option was removed completely. I suspect it's the same with Outlook 365

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gmail Error :The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not)

Comment: I will review this information later, I am supposed to be working now. This looks promising. Thank you.

Comment: That link says `you can't`. It's not exactly promising. A better idea would be to install a small SMTP server on your machine that only listens to SQL Server. In the past, IIS came with an SMTP service but that was discontinued.

Comment: If it's a dev machine, you can add a Docker container with an SMTP service

Comment: OK. Thank you. You save me a lot of time. I guess database mail is no longer a function in SQL Server Developer.

Comment: On the contrary, Database mail is still alive and well. You still need an email server though, and neither Gmail nor Office 365 allow their SMTP servers to be used that way any more, at least not for free accounts. They were being abused for spam and fraud and identity spoofing, so all providers first increased security, then dropped the feature altogether. Their cloud divisions have their own, paid, mass mailing offerings.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will try to find something that works with SQL Server Developer.