# JavaMail - Unable to send mail using SSL

Tags: java, email, ssl, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send the mail by enabling SSL using JavaMail with office365 as host. When I'm using the host as `smtp.gmail.com` then it's working fine but not working for `smtp.office365.com` Below is my approach:

```
public class SendMail
{

     public static void main(String args[]){
        String username = "abc@xyz.com";
        String password = "abc123";
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port",995);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");

        Session session = null;

        if (authenticationRequired) {
          session = Session.getInstance(properties,
              new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(userName,password);
                }
              });
        }else{
             session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);  
       }
       try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setSubject("Test mail");
            message.setContent("Test Mail", "text/html");
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(john@gmail.com));

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect();
            transport.sendMessage(message,message.getAllRecipients());
       }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStack();
       }
     }
  }
```

It is throwing exception as - `Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 995 response: -1`. I have also tried the port as `993` but that too also not working. Kindly help me out. `Other approaches are also welcome`

Comment: I haven't an answer for your problem, but I used this library [https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/) for sending mails....and worked well.  Try it! Is built on top of the Java Mail API.

Comment: What's the output if you start your program with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, works with gmail did you import the gmail´s certificate to your keystore?

Comment: Try to add this: props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtpserver");

Comment: I tried that one also but getting same error....and I didn't import the Certificate

Comment: Try to use port 587 or take a look this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244694/send-smtp-email-using-system-net-mail-via-exchange-online-office-365

Comment: I tried with port 587 also, but I got the error like - `Failed to connect host: office365 and Port 25` though we are using the port `587`