# Send mail from Office365 on godaddy servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

For an app I am writing an api service in c#. The site is hosted on a godaddy server. We have a office 365 account as well. I am trying to send main in my c# code through this accounts credentials. Earlier we had elasticemail smtp account. The same code was working fire with elasticemail account. But this code is not working with office 365 account.

```
smtpClient.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
                    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtpClient.Port = 25;
                    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                    MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("my365email@domain.com");
                    MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress("toaddress@yahoo.com");
                    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my365email@domain.com", "password");
                    message.From = fromAddress;
                    message.To.Add(toAddress);
                    message.Subject = "This is the subject line";
                    message.Body = "This is a test mail";
                    smtpClient.Send(message);
```

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Comment: Unable to connect to the remote server error

Comment: Looks like you are using wrong port. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244694/send-smtp-email-using-system-net-mail-via-exchange-online-office-365

Comment: I copied the code from godaddy community site.

Comment: Tried both 25 and 587 ports still same error.

Comment: Then you might need to contact GoDaddy.