# Send email from .NET Core using Microsoft 365 Family subscription

Tags: c#, email, .net-core, office365, office365api

I have an Office 365 Family subscription (thus using outlook.com) and are trying to send email from a C# application I'm working on. Does anybody know if this is even possible?
From my research there seems to be a lot of people having issue with this approach but I'm trying hard to find out if it's supported

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of doing the required job:

1. Use standard .net mechanisms, the same question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244694/send-smtp-email-using-system-net-mail-via-exchange-online-office-365):

```
            using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()
            {
                Host = "smtp.office365.com",
                Port = 587,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false, // This require to be before setting Credentials property
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("alias@fulldomain.com", "password"), // you must give a full email address for authentication 
                TargetName = "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com", // Set to avoid MustIssueStartTlsFirst exception
                EnableSsl = true // Set to avoid secure connection exception
            })
            {

                MailMessage message = new MailMessage()
                {
                    From = new MailAddress("alias@fulldomain.com"), // sender must be a full email address
                    Subject = subject,
                    IsBodyHtml = true,
                    Body = "<h1>Hello World</h1>",
                    BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                    SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,

                };
                var toAddresses = recipients.Split(',');
                foreach (var to in toAddresses)
                {
                    message.To.Add(to.Trim());
                }

                try
                {
                    client.Send(message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

The `SmtpClient` is usable in .NET Core, but its use isn't recommended. Instead, consider using https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit .

2. Use [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Answer (score 0):

And for anybody else having problems with using smtp.office365.com and sending email through code. You need to add an "app password" in your Microsoft Account. The regular password you use to login to outlook.com will not work

Comment: Adding a link on how to do this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/email-delivery/fix-issues-with-printers-scanners-and-lob-applications-that-send-email-using-off#error-authentication-unsuccessful