# Sending ics file with MailKit and Stringbuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, mailkit

I'm trying to send an email with a calendar invite, as an ics file attachment. I'm using Mailkit, as my understanding is the system.net.mail is deprecated.

After playing with it, I understand that the "bodybuilder" is looking for a filepath, but that's not what I'm trying to do here, and so I'm sort of lost.

Alot of the documentation on the web seems to be outdated...

```
public IActionResult ThrEmail(string sendto, string subject, string body)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sendto))
        {
            //construct mail
            var message = new MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("nick", "nic-fleetwood@behr.travel"));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(sendto));
            message.Subject = subject;
            //message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
            //{
            //    Text = body
            //};

            BodyBuilder emailBody = new BodyBuilder();
            emailBody.TextBody = body;

            //ics file -- use yyyMMddTHHmmssZ format
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            //str.AppendLine()
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
            str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//RYNE MOVING//EN");
            str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
            str.AppendLine("METHOD:PUBLISH");
            //THE EVENT
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
            str.AppendLine("DTSTART:20210215T100000");
            str.AppendLine("DTEND:20210215T110000");
            str.AppendLine("DTSTAMP:" + DateTime.Now);
            str.AppendLine("UID:" + Guid.NewGuid());
            str.AppendLine("CREATED:" + DateTime.Now);
            str.AppendLine("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:");
            //sb.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:" + res.Details);
            str.AppendLine("LAST-MODIFIED:" + DateTime.Now);
            str.AppendLine("LOCATION:NYC");
            str.AppendLine("SEQUENCE:0");
            str.AppendLine("STATUS:CONFIRMED");
            str.AppendLine("SUMMARY:");
            str.AppendLine("TRANSP:OPAQUE");
            str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");

            str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

            emailBody.Attachments.Add(str.ToString());

            //send the email
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                client.Connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, false);

                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                client.Authenticate("nic-fleetwood@behr.travel", "foobar");

                client.Send(message);
                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AttachmentCollection](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_AttachmentCollection.htm) has several methods to add the specified attachment.

You need to use this one [Add(String, Stream)](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_AttachmentCollection_Add_5.htm):

```cs
var emailBody = new BodyBuilder();

var ics = new StringBuilder();
/* initialize calendar options */

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write(ics.ToString());

        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        emailBody.Attachments.Add("calendar.ics", stream);
    }
}
```

or [Add(string, byte[])](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_AttachmentCollection_Add_3.htm):

```cs
emailBody.Attachments.Add("calendar.ics", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ics.ToString()));
```

Comment: so when I used ".Add("calendar.ics", stream);" i got "ArgumentException: The stream cannot be read. (Parameter 'stream')". when I used your edit, for "Encoding" the email went but no attachment

Comment: @NickFleetwood just check: did you do  *message.Body = emailbody.ToMessageBody ();*? (see for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853903/can-i-send-files-via-email-using-mailkit/)