# failed to send the file by Email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, rdlc

I am created a report viewer using rdlc report system. but the problem is got, when I send this file by email then I found an error. My program is something like that:-

at first, I created a reporting process, which shows my "Order" database's all information. that information shows me as one file system on my desktop when I run my application. this file, I want to send by email. but when I trying to send this, I found many errors.

Here is my code:-

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> CheckOut(Order11 anOrder)
   {

      //other code


         
                //report process



                string mimetype = "";
                int extension = 1;
                var path = $"{this._webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\Reports\\Report2.rdlc";
                Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                var products = _db.Order.ToList();
                LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport(path);
                localReport.AddDataSource("DataSet1", products);

                var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, extension, parameters, mimetype);

                 var s= File(result.MainStream, "application/pdf");
              
                

                //report process end




                //Email Sender start



                var email = anOrder.Email;
                var message = new MimeMessage();
                message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Ghatia Bazar",
                "pri@gmail.com"));
                message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("pritom", email));
                message.Subject = "Order Details";
                message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
                {
                    Text = "Hi,Thanks For Order.",
                };
                //add attach
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                BodyBuilder bb = new BodyBuilder();
                using (var wc = new WebClient())
                {
                   
                    bb.Attachments.Add("s",
                    wc.DownloadData("path"));
                  

                }

                message.Body = bb.ToMessageBody();
                //end attach
                using (var client = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
                    client.Authenticate("pri@gmail.com",
                    "MyPassword");
                    client.Send(message);
                    client.Disconnect(true);
                }


                //Email sender end


//other code
```

I also use `bb.Attachments.Add("s", result.MainStream);`  instead of   `bb.Attachments.Add("s", wc.DownloadData("path"));`   when I use this, then I found an unexpected email. In this email's file, I found a lot of code.   so now  `bb.Attachments.Add("s", wc.DownloadData("path"));`  I am using this process to attach a file.  but here I found a different error.

Here is my output:-

[image]

How I will solve this problem.How I send my created file by email. I am still a beginner, please help.

Comment: What's the purpose of code block `using (var wc = new WebClient())` ? You don't need it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853903/can-i-send-files-via-email-using-mailkit

Comment: `wc.DownloadData("path"));` are you sure you want the quotes there...?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I want my created file to send by mail. I using ```  wc.DownloadData("path")); ``` for sending mail.

Comment: yeah. i get that. i got that when i read the code. my question is: do you want to download it to a file named `"path"`, or to the filepath you declared in your _variable_ `path`...?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya please clarify the code, where should change my code for sending the file.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I declare a variable "path".here path i use for creating file process. ```  wc.DownloadData("path")); ``` and here is used just my experiment to know that it's work or not for send mail

Comment: @FranzGleichmann and I don't want download to the filename path

Comment: " and I don't want download to the filename path" - and that's what you're ***doing*** by using `"path"` instead of `path`.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Now i am using a path instead of "path".error gone, but in this file, I can not see my database information which i want

Comment: @FranzGleichmann This Email file shows a lot of code. which is not expected

Comment: You can attach the file by doing `bb.Attachments.Add("Myfile.pdf", result.MainStream.Stream);`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i found a red error below "Stream". error is "byte[] does not contain the definition of a 'stream'"

Comment: Sorry, I think `.Stream` is not needed... you can try `bb.Attachments.Add("Myfile.pdf", result.MainStream);`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks a lot, works perfectly. if you answer my question, I will accept your answer :)

Comment: I think you are trying to use `AspNetCore.Reporting` for generating reports. This library is  last updated in 2018 and it is not being developed actively. You should look for some other option for creating reportes in asp.net core.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya you are right, can you tell me please what other option I should follow for reports as an intermidiate level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code it looks like you are using AspNetCore.Reporting library for generating reports from RDLC files.

Code of this library is available on GitHub at https://github.com/amh1979/AspNetCore.Reporting

LocalReport class from this library has `Execute` method which return an instance of `ReportResult` class.

Code of both these classes is located at https://github.com/amh1979/AspNetCore.Reporting/blob/master/AspNetCore.Reporting/LocalReport.cs

`ReportResult` class has a Property `MainStream` which represents the content of the report as Byte Array.

Now, attachment to MimeMessage via BodyBuilder support various inputs for file contents such as Stream, byte[] etc.

With this knowledge, I think you can directly use `ReportResult.MainStream` to attach file to the BodyBuilder.

You can change your code as following to make it working.

```
var path = $"{this._webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\Reports\\Report2.rdlc";
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var products = _db.Order.ToList();
LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport(path);
localReport.AddDataSource("DataSet1", products);

//Following line of code returns an instance of ReportResult class
var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, extension, parameters, mimetype);

var email = anOrder.Email;
var message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Ghatia Bazar", "pri@gmail.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("pritom", email));
message.Subject = "Order Details";
message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
{
    Text = "Hi,Thanks For Order.",
};
var bb = new BodyBuilder();

// Following line will attach the report as "MyFile.pdf".
// You can use filename of your choice.
bb.Attachments.Add("Myfile.pdf", result.MainStream);

message.Body = bb.ToMessageBody();

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
    client.Authenticate("pri@gmail.com", "MyPassword");
    client.Send(message);
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

I hope this will help you resolve your issue.