# How can I send an email with MimeKit in C#

Tags: c#, email, email-attachments, mailkit, mimekit

Hi everyone I'm trying to send an email using the MimeKit  but I'm trying to attach a .pdf file I have some problems:

This is how I'm trying to send it:

```
 private bool EnviarMail(string file, string from, string to, string subject, string content, string name)
    {
        bool estado = false;

        try
        {
            var mensaje = new MimeMessage();
            mensaje.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(name, from));
            mensaje.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", to));
            mensaje.Subject = subject;

            var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
            bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = content;
            bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add(file);
            mensaje.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

            using (var client = new SmtpClient("myHost", myPort))
            {
                client.Send(mensaje);    
            }

            estado = true;
            return estado;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return estado;
        }
    }
```

But I have this error on `client.send(mensaje)` line. It says:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MimeKit.MimeMessage' to ' System.Net.Mail.MailMessage'

How can I send this email correctly?

I tried what is was told here : [Can I send files via email using MailKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853903/can-i-send-files-via-email-using-mailkit)

But I couldn't do it for same error

Comment: Are you using the SMTP Client in MimeKit or the one in System.Net.Mail? Given the error it's the latter. Why aren't you use MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient?

Comment: MimeKit does not give me a SMTP Client, I don't know why, I followed same steps of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8tLIG20qF8&t=376s (Send Email using MimeKit and MailKit Package)

Comment: Can you post your "using ... " section?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to watch a video to figure out what you're trying to do!

Comment: _"MimeKit does not give me a SMTP Client,"_ - How come? What happens when you try?

Comment: Yes, It was to show where I got the information

Comment: Have you added MailKit and added `using MailKit.Net.Smtp;` to your file?

Comment: Thank you everyone, I had only MimeKit but not MailKit, my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that you are using the wrong SMTP client!

You should be using the one that comes with MimeKit ([MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient.htm)) and not the one in .NET ([System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0))

Note that MimeKit and MailKit work hand-in-hand with MimeKit devoted to the parsing and handling of messages. Where as MailKit concerns the network aspects of sending and receiving messages.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'MailKit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I got this

Comment: Have you got the appropriate using? `using MailKit.Net.Smtp;` notice that this is MailKit (which is part of MimeKit)

Comment: It was not downloaded, I only had MimeKit but not MailKit...