# Run Powershell Script on Boot without being logged in

Tags: windows, powershell

have searched around but cant get this to work. I have as PS script that sends email on server boot. It works when I run it through a cmd file. I have setup a Task under Task Scheduler to run that cmd file and selected 'Run whether user is logged in or not' and also 'Run wit highest privileges'

When I restart the PC it doesnt run the script.

The script only gets run when I log in.

Any ideas please?

---

When computer starts. Sent output to log as suggested get this:

---

Exception calling "Send" with "4" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
At C:\Users\ravlo\sendEmail.ps1:9 char:1
+ $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException

---

Full Script is this:

---

```
$EmailFrom = "x"
$EmailTo = "y"
$Subject = "SERVER JUST REBOOTED"
$Body = "z"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("emaillogin", "emailpwd");
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

---

Runs OK when I actually log in.

Comment: What `Trigger` did you select for the task?  `When the computer starts` or `When I log on`?  What `Actions` did you configure for the task?  What does the `History`/`Last Run Result` show for that task?  Are you sure the script isn't running at all vs. only the email part of it is failing?  Can you write to a log within the script to see what it's doing and when?  I don't think `Run with highest privileges` is necessary, and, depending on your email system, the user as which the script is run might not be significant.

Comment: hi edited original post with details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending mail using SmtpClient in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470645/sending-mail-using-smtpclient-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

Can you test your mail server accessibility before you execute Send() ? You can add

```
if ((Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $SMTPServer -Port 25).TcpTestSucceeded) {
    $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
} else {
    Write-Output "SMTP Server not accessible"
}
```

If you have Windows Pro and higher, you can use Group Policy startup scripts in Computer configuration scope.