# Populating a field using multiple field values

Tags: c#, xml, infopath, auto-populating

I'm using InfoPath 2007, and coding in C#. What I want to do is populate the field **Contract Number**, with multiple fields, being **Contract Period End Date** (**dtTo**, which has to be in the format **YYYY/MM**, which is a datepicker that was selected), **Project Number** (**ddlPortfolio**, a drop down list selected), **Sequence Number** (which is retrieved from the database, SQL Server 2005) and Fund Type (**bFundType**, an Option button selected).

Now what I have done is that I have used a method to try to populate the field Contract Number. The method is called Generate ContractNo, which goes:

```
public string GenerateContractNo()
    {
        string sSequence = "";

        //IPCode.popSeq(this.CreateNavigator(), this.NamespaceManager, DataSources, this.MainDataSource);


        //string seqNo = this.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myRoot/my:SectionHeading/my:sSequence", NamespaceManager).InnerXml;



        string sPortfolio = this.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myRoot/my:SectionHeading/my:ddlPortfolio", NamespaceManager).InnerXml;
        string sYear = this.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myRoot/my:SectionHeading/my:dtTo", NamespaceManager).InnerXml;
        string sMonth = this.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myRoot/my:SectionHeading/my:dtTo", NamespaceManager).InnerXml;
        //string sSeq = this.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myRoot/my:SectionHeading/my:sSequence", NamespaceManager).InnerXml;
        string sFundType = this.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myRoot/my:SectionHeading/my:bFundType", NamespaceManager).InnerXml;

        //Convert.ToInt16(sSeq);

       // return sYear + "/" + sMonth + "/" + sPortfolio + "/" + sSeq + "/" + sFundType;

        sSequence = sYear + "/" + sMonth + "/" + sPortfolio + "/" + sFundType;

        this.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myRoot/my:SectionHeading/my:sSequence", this.NamespaceManager).SetValue(sSequence); 

        //CourseDetails = dtSDate.ToLongDateString() + " - " + dtEDate.ToLongDateString() + " | " + sLocation + " | " + SDCategory;

        //CourseDetailsFields = sTitle + "|" + dtSDate.ToLongDateString() + "|" + dtEDate.ToLongDateString() + "|" + sLocation + "|" + SDCategory;

        //lstDetails.Add(CourseDetailsFields, CourseDetailsFields); 
        return null;

    }
```

I've tried to also use a class called PopSeq, to populate the Sequence Number field, with a sequence number from the Database, which calls a stored procedure called, uspGetSeqNo. The following is the class, as well as the stored procedure:

```
static public int popSeq(XPathNavigator xnMyForm, XmlNamespaceManager ns, DataSourceCollection ds, DataSource mds)
    {

        try
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(IPCode.defaultConnectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[uspGetSeqNo]", conn);

            conn.Open();            
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //XPathNavigator domNav = mds.CreateNavigator();
            //string sVendor = domNav.SelectSingleNode("/my:myRoot/my:SectionHeading/my:ddlVendor", this.NamespaceManager).ToString();

            //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iSequence", s);

            SqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader();



            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string iSequence = Convert.ToString(myReader.GetOrdinal("iSequence"));
               //return Convert.ToInt16(sSeq);                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Stored Procedure:

```
USE [TAU_PANEL]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[uspGetSeqNo]    Script Date: 04/06/2011      08:52:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetSeqNo]

AS

SELECT     MAX(iSequence) + 1 AS seq
FROM         dbo.ResAllocations
```

So my problem is that, on the button save , it doesn't populate the Contract Number field. Sorry as I'm a novice to C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you don't need the return value of `GenerateContractNo`, so make the method to have a return type of `void`. To set the value, try using this code instead:

```
this.CreateNavigator().
    SelectSingleNode("/my:myRoot/my:SectionHeading/my:sSequence", 
        this.NamespaceManager).InnerText = sSequence;
```

Background:
According to the documentation for the [`Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value.aspx), it is null for Element nodes. Your sSequence node most likely *is* an Element node.

About your method `popSeq`:

- Don't rethrow exceptions with `throw ex`. See the following question for more info: [what can lead throw to reset a callstack (I'm using "throw", not "throw ex")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152265/what-can-lead-throw-to-reset-a-callstack-im-using-throw-not-throw-ex).
- Don't catch exceptions, if you don't handle them (rethrowing doesn't count as handling!)