# VB.net throwing error to parent

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a question about how to properly deal with errors.  I am working on a three tiered application.  If an error is created on the data tier, I would like to pass the error to the business tier and process it there.  What is the best method to accomplish this?  I am using .net 2.0 and visual studio 2005.

Thanks for any advice
jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Try...Catch` in your business-layer with your calls to your data-layer within the Try.

```
Try
  'call data-layer
Catch ex As Exception
  'deal with exception / log
End Try
```

If you still want to use `Try...Catch` in your data-layer then you need to `Throw` (to preserve stacktrace) or `Throw ex` within the Catch, otherwise don't use `Try...Catch` in your data-layer at all.

```
Try
  data = dataLayer.GetData()
Catch ex As Exception
  Throw
End Try
```

Comment: Note: use `Throw` instead of `Throw ex` to keep the stacktrace. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex Otherwise you wouldn't see that the exception actually was raised in `DoWork` or even in "deeper" methods called from `DoWork`.

Comment: Changed my answer to reflect this advice. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!  I will implement this