# Catch vs Catch (Exception e) and Throw vs Throw e

Tags: c#, try-catch

Are these two code examples the same? **Catch** and **Catch (Exception e)** have the same output, and the result is also the same if I write **Throw** or **Throw e**.

Main:

```
try
{
    A();
    //B();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} exception caught.", e);
}
```

Code 1:

```
static void A()
{
    try
    {
        int value = 1 / int.Parse("0");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Code 2:

```
static void A()
{
    // Rethrow syntax.
    try
    {
        int value = 1 / int.Parse("0");
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both are the same because you `throw`.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Marc yes if he `throws e` there is a difference.

Comment: Got it, I just wanted to re-tag but I see that has already been taken care of!

Comment: What is the point of `throw e`, as you throw the exception but with the the useful part of stacktrace missing

Comment: @JonH already deleted my comment - misread the question ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell It was updated by Paul, was missing tag before that.

Comment: @MarcGravell isnt it amazing how fast people read the comments / posts and post back.

Comment: Somewhere on here this is a duplicate question - just cant find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between "throw" and "throw ex"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex)

Comment: @spender the difference is actually `catch` vs `catch(Exception ex)`

Comment: @MarcGravell catch and catch(Exception ex) is practically the same right? As they will both catch all exceptions, but the latter one will allow you to use the information? like logg it etc

Comment: @Fuji - They both will catch the exception being thrown.  The difference is the first condition `catch(Exception ex)` has a reference to an exception, namely `ex`, while the second doesn't.

Comment: @Fuji in .NET 1.1 with unmanaged exceptions, it could be different. Doesn't really happen any more though,

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I think there are two questions here.

---

**What is the difference between `throw` and `throw e;`?**

I don't think there is ever a good reason to write `catch (Exception e) { throw e; }`. This loses the original stacktrace. When you use `throw;` the original stacktrace is preserved. This is good because it means that the cause of the error is easier to find.

---

**What is the difference between `catch` and `catch (Exception e)`?**

Both of your examples are the same and equally useless - they just catch an exception and then rethrow it. One minor difference is that the first example will generate a compiler warning.

> The variable 'e' is declared but never used

It makes more sense to ask this question if you had some other code in your catch block that actually does something useful. For example you might want to log the exception:

```
try
{
    int value = 1 / int.Parse("0");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    LogException(e);
    throw;
}
```

Now it's necessary to use the first version so that you have a reference to the caught exception.

If your catch block doesn't actually use the exception then you would want to use the second version to avoid the compiler warning.

Comment: I updated the code I just wanted to know if its matter to write Exception e / Throw e because the result is same..

Comment: @Loclip: If you care about not losing the stacktrace, and if you care about not having compiler warnings when you compile your code (and you *should* care about these things) then, yes, it does matter.

Comment: It's also possible to specify the exception type to catch without introducing a local variable (which the compiler complains is never used). You just say: `catch (ArithmeticException) { ... }`

Answer (score 39):

If we ignore the "unused variable" warning, the only time there is a **practical** difference between

```
catch {...}
```

and

```
catch(Exception ex) {...}
```

is when some non-C# code is throwing a non-`Exception` exception. C++ can throw ***anything***. In .NET 1.1, you **had** to use `catch` (no `(Exception ex)`) to handle these unusual exceptions. However, this was problematic - not least, you can't see what was thrown! So in .NET 2.0 and above this is wrapped by default, so even if C++ throws, say, a `string` - you see it as an `Exception` subclass. Note that this can be disabled via a configuration setting, but: don't. Leave it alone!

The issue of `throw;` vs `throw ex;` is already mentioned, and relates to stack-traces. You can use `throw` in both cases, causing the original stack-trace to be preserved.

Comment: For purely educational purposes, do you have a link for further information on this configuration setting? Or if you do not wish to tempt fate by linking it here, may I DM you on twitter? I am currently unable to find out more information about it.

Comment: Another practical concern- if I don't have "catch(Exception ex) {...}" then I won't know what the exception is when I am debugging. Unless I am mistaken and there is a way to see the exception in empty "catch{..}" statements...

Comment: This has been available for a while, but you can use `$exception` in the watch window: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943373/how-to-see-exception-detail-in-debugger-without-assigning-variable-to-exception

Comment: Or you can see it in the 'Locals' tab.