# How to see exception detail in debugger without assigning variable to exception?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

I want to see  exception detail in visual studio debugger without assigning variable to exception. Currently I have to write something like this:

```
try 
{
    //some code
}
catch (SecurityException ex)
{
   //some code or ever no any code 
}
```

Visual studio throws an error indicating that ex variable is never used, but i need this variable to see exception detail while debugging.

UPDATE: I know how to suppress VS error 'variable is never used', problem is in seeing exception inside watch without this variable.

---

$exception variable by @VladimirFrolov or exception helper by @MarcGravell is an answer.

Comment: Add throw ex; in your catch? Or Console.WriteLine(ex.getMessage()); or any other value

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can see your exception in Locals list or use `$exception` in Watch list:

```
try
{
    // some code
}
catch (SecurityException)
{ // place breakpoint at this line
}
```

Comment: Is this still true for VS.NET 2017 ?  Doesn't seem to work with vs2017

Comment: @FrederikGheysels, I always use `$exception` in VS2017 and it works just fine.

Comment: still works in VS 2019. excellent solution; but very obscure: VS really could have improved on that by showing some clue on mousehover.

Comment: doesn't work `identifier "$exception" is undefined` _(thinking about it, it's probably because it's caught internally by the binary library that causes it)_

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to do anything: just put a breakpoint inside the `catch` (or on a `catch` and step once into the block) and you should see an invitation to see the exception helper. This works for naked `catch` or for type-specific `catch(SecurityException)` blocks:

[image]

which gives you everything:

[image]

Comment: My problem with this dialog is if there are messages in the "Data" collection, I can't seem to view them through this dialog. Is there a way?

Comment: Is it possible that Visual Studio 2015 doesn't have this feature anymore? At least it just enters the `catch` block without offering any helper, just like with any other line of code, no matter where I place the breakpoint.

Comment: @Andrew this is what I have seen as well. I asked about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872167/where-did-the-exception-helper-go-for-visual-studio-2015

Comment: This feature used to work in older VS versions but now it's stopped working for me with VS 2015.  Maybe there's a way to reactivate it.  I'm glad to learn about $exception as a less convenient but very usable alternative.

Answer (score 8):

At any moment when you hit the exception you can check the Watch Window and add variable: `$exception`.
This will let you work with all the Exception metadata.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a functionality from Visual Studio.

Debug => Exceptions => Check "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"

That's it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
catch (SecurityException /*without variable*/)
{/*break Point*/
   //some code or ever no any code 
}
```

or

```
catch /*without parameter*/
{/*break Point*/
   //some code or ever no any code 
}
```

but i think this is what you mean

```
catch (SecurityException ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); //for Winforms
       Console.WriteLine(ex); //for console
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

just write

```
 catch
{//set breakpoint here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid getting the warning: "The variable 'ex' is declared but never used" in a catch statement,do the following:

```
 try
 {
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
   // set break point 
 }
```

Or use  [System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz.aspx) or Enable tracing or debugging to use a [trace listener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx).

Comment: You do realize this is not what Danila is asking, right?

Comment: This isn't even trying to answer the asked question.