# Where did the exception assistant go for Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, exception, visual-studio-debugging

For a handled exception in Visual Studio 2013 I could view the exception dialog in a catch block by clicking the red exception helper icon. In Visual Studio 2015 this is missing. The dialog still shows when the exception is thrown, so that is not the issue. Though there is a workaround in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15943394/5301903), this doesn't provide the functionality of the exception dialog (e.g. copy to clipboard).

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see exception detail in debugger without assigning variable to exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943373/how-to-see-exception-detail-in-debugger-without-assigning-variable-to-exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's no longer there, so you have to watch `$exception`, which always has the current exception object.

According to [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/27001/exception-helper-window-lost.html), I'd try enabling/disabling `Tools | Options > Debugging | General | Use the new Exception Helper`, or trying the update mentioned in this message, posted on Dec 5th 2017:

> This issue has been fixed and is now available in our latest update. You can download the update via the in-product notification or from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/

Comment: I agree that it appears to be removed, but I have not been able to see this confirmed anywhere. This [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/) address changes to the settings, but doesn't mention the removal of this feature.

Comment: I found another article you may find interesting. I've added it to the solution.

Comment: The linked article is referring to Visual Studio 2017. I can check to see if there is an update for Visual Studio 2015. I am using update 3.

Comment: In VS2015 the option is called "Enable the exception assistant", in the same place.