# App terminates when using Thread in Xamarin/C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to run some code in a new thread because I'm noticing a slowness on my device. It is compiling ok but at the app starting, it freezes and terminates with the message (MyApp is presenting errors constantly).

What I'm doing wrong?

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() => {
                TestaLogin();
            })).Start();
        }

        private void TestaLogin()
        {
            try
            {
                Context mContext = Android.App.Application.Context;
                ISharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
                string uid = pref.GetString("uid", "0");
                string token = pref.GetString("token", "0");

                if (uid == "0" || token == "0")
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { MainPage = new Login(); });
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Logar(uid, token))
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { MainPage = new MainPage(uid); });
                    else
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { MainPage = new Login(); });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        private bool Logar(string user, string pass)
        {
            try
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    return client.DownloadString("https://www.example.com/mobile/login.php?u=" + user + "&t=" + pass) == "0" ? false : true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also wanted to know if lines like this has to be inside the MainThread, I thought that because it's handling changing the page:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { MainPage = new MainPage(uid); });
```

Comment: Have you tried `Task.Run`? It's a more modern way of multi threading. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429129/task-vs-thread-differences

Comment: if it crashes, you need to determine the cause of the crash.  Step through it in the debugger, use logging, add try/catch, etc - to find the root exception causing the crash

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I will take a look, had not seen yet.

Comment: And, perhaps you can put a break point at the `re-throw` of the exception. ... btw, you should use `throw;` see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805987/catch-vs-catch-exception-e-and-throw-vs-throw-e

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm trying with Tasks.