# ToAsyncEnumerable().Single() vs SingleAsync()

Tags: entity-framework, linq, system.reactive, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I'm constructing and executing my queries in a way that's independent of EF-Core, so I'm relying on `IQueryable<T>` to obtain the required level of abstraction.  I'm replacing awaited `SingleAsync()` calls with awaited `ToAsyncEnumerable().Single()` calls.  I'm also replacing `ToListAsync()` calls with `ToAsyncEnumerable().ToList()` calls.  But I just happened upon the `ToAsyncEnumerable()` method so I'm unsure I'm using it correctly or not.

To clarify which extension methods I'm referring to, they're defined as follows:

- `SingleAsync` and `ToListAsync` are defined on the `EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions` class in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace and assembly.
- `ToAsyncEnumerable` is defined on the `AsyncEnumerable` class in the `System.Linq` namespace in the `System.Interactive.Async` assembly.

When the query runs against EF-Core, are the calls `ToAsyncEnumerable().Single()/ToList()` versus `SingleAsync()/ToListAsync()` equivalent in function and performance?  If not then how do they differ?

Comment: Do you, by chance, mean "AsAsyncEnumerable"?

Comment: @EyalPerry No, it's definitely `ToAsyncEnumerable` in said assembly.

Comment: I'd validate any answer you receive by looking at the generated SQL using SQL Profiler to make sure that any Single call manifests itself as a TOP 2 in the query like it should.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For methods returning sequence (like `ToListAsync`, `ToArrayAsync`) I don't expect a difference.

However for single value returning methods (the async versions of `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single`, `Min`, `Max`, `Sum` etc.) definitely there will be a difference. It's the same as the difference by executing those methods on `IQueryable<T>` vs `IEnumerable<T>`. In the former case they are processed by database query returning a single value to the client while in the later the whole result set will be returned to the client and processed in memory.

So, while in general the idea of abstracting EF Core is good, it will cause performance issues with `IQueryable<T>` because the async processing of queryables is not standartized, and converting to `IEnumerable<T>` changes the execution context, hence the implementation of single value returning LINQ methods.

P.S. By standardization I mean the following. The synchronous processing of `IQueryable` is provided by `IQueryProvider` (**standard** interface from `System.Linq` namespace in `System.Core.dll` assembly) `Execute` methods. Asynchronous processing would require introducing another **standard** interface similar to EF Core **custom** `IAsyncQueryProvider` (inside `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal` namespace in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll` assembly). Which I guess requires cooperation/approval from the BCL team and takes time, that's why they decided to take a custom path for now.

Comment: I confirmed that this answer is correct by comparing the generated SQL as @usr suggested.  You said, "the async processing of queryables is not standardized".  How could it be standardized?  Maybe a `ToAsyncQueryable` method?

Comment: I went ahead and [requested](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/294) this feature.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. A standard `IAsyncQueryProvider` interface already exists, but it's not being fully utilized. See my feature request for more details.

Comment: I saw it. The problem is thought the Rx is also a custom extensions library, hence not part of the standard BCL like `IQueryProvider`, `IQueryable`, `IEnumerable` etc.

Comment: EF-Core ([current](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/) | [preview](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetcore-dev/package/nuget/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore)) references `System.Interactive.Async` (Ix), so I don't think that's an issue.

Comment: @HappyNomad I see. Well, good luck then, will be watching it :)

Answer (score 1):

When the original source is a `DbSet`, `ToAsyncEnumerable().Single()` is not as performant as `SingleAsync()` in the exceptional case where the database contains more than one matching row.  But in in the more likely scenario, where you both expect and receive only one row, it's the same.  Compare the generated SQL:

```
SingleAsync():
    SELECT TOP(2) [l].[ID]
    FROM [Ls] AS [l]

ToAsyncEnumerable().Single():
    SELECT [l].[ID]
    FROM [Ls] AS [l]
```

`ToAsyncEnumerable()` breaks the `IQueryable` call chain and enters LINQ-to-Objects land.  Any downstream filtering occurs in memory.  You can mitigate this problem by doing your filtering upstream.  So instead of:

```
ToAsyncEnumerable().Single( l => l.Something == "foo" ):
    SELECT [l].[ID], [l].[Something]
    FROM [Ls] AS [l]
```

you can do:

```
Where( l => l.Something == "foo" ).ToAsyncEnumerable().Single():
    SELECT [l].[ID], [l].[Something]
    FROM [Ls] AS [l]
    WHERE [l].[Something] = N'foo'
```

If that approach still leaves you squirmish then, as an alternative, consider defining extension methods like this one:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal;

static class Extensions
{
    public static Task<T> SingleAsync<T>( this IQueryable<T> source ) =>
        source.Provider is IAsyncQueryProvider
            ? EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.SingleAsync( source )
            : Task.FromResult( source.Single() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Microsoft documentation for EF Core (all versions, including the current 2.1 one):

> *This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.*

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.internal.asynclinqoperatorprovider.toasyncenumerable?view=efcore-2.1

p.s. I personally found it problematic in combination with the AutoMapper tool (at least, until ver. 6.2.2) - it just doesn't map collection of type IAsyncEnumerable  (unlike IEnumerable, with which the AutoMapper works seamlessly).

Comment: You are referring to the property variant of ToAsyncEnumerable; not the method (which is an extension found in the System.Interactive.Async package by .NET Foundation and Contributors). Have a look here (hard to track down): https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/ToAsyncEnumerable.cs

Answer (score -1):

I took a peek at the source code of [Single](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive.Async/Single.cs) (Line 90).
It cleary illustrates that the enumerator is only advanced once (for a successful operation).

```
        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!await e.MoveNext(cancellationToken)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(Strings.NO_ELEMENTS);
            }
            var result = e.Current;
            if (await e.MoveNext(cancellationToken)
                       .ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(Strings.MORE_THAN_ONE_ELEMENT);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Since this kind of implementation is as good as it gets (nowadays), one can say with certainty that using the Ix Single Operator would not harm performance.

As for SingleAsync, you can be sure that it is implemented in a similar manner, and even if it is not (which is doubtful), it could not outperform the Ix Single operator.

Comment: Thanks but how does this relate to `SingleAsync`?

Comment: I will edit my answer, but the gist of it is- Entity framework would do the same.. It would load the first result at some point and attempt to determine if there's another. There really isn't any better way to do it, so performance will certainly not be harmed.

Comment: This isn't correct. SingleAsync on an IQueryable should always outperform Single on any kind of Enumerable that wraps a Queryable

Comment: It enumerates the whole sequence, though, giving EF no chance to pull just one item from the database.

Comment: Thanks for trying @EyalPerry, but your reasoning is incomplete.  If you looked at `SingleAsync`, you'd notice it operates on `IQueryable` and thus uses the query provider.  `ToAsyncEnumerable.Single` doesn't use `IQueryable`.

Comment: @HappyNomad Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: Since this answer is incorrect, it really should just be deleted.