# difference between throw and throw ex in c# .net

Tags: c#, throw

Can anyone tell me difference between `throw` and `throw ex` in brief?
I read that `throw` stores previous exceptions, not getting this line.
Can i get this in brief with example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex

Comment: `throw`, without a parameter is used in a `catch` block to rethrow an exception that caused the `catch`.

Answer (score 30):

Yes - `throw` re-throws the exception that was caught, and preserves the stack trace.  `throw ex` throws the same exception, but *resets the stack trace* to that method.

Unless you *want* to reset the stack trace (i.e. to shield public callers from the internal workings of your library), `throw` is *generally* the better choice, since you can see where the exception originated.

I would also mention that a "pass-through" catch block:

```
try
{
   // do stuff
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

is pointless.  It's the exact same behavior as if there were no `try/catch` at all.

Comment: Its not pointless if you put a log statement before throw. Thats how I use it quite often.

Comment: @Eugene You are right, but I don't have anything before the throw - that's what I was intending to illustrate.

Answer (score 5):

Throw will rethrow original exception;

throw ex will create a new exception, so the stack trace changes. Usually makes little sense, in general you should either just throw, or create a new exception and throw that, eg

```
// not a great code, demo purposes only
try{
File.Read("blah");
}
catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
throw new ConfigFileNotFoundException("Oops", ex);
}
```

Comment: I have used this pattern, the `throw new Exception...`, on more than one occasion, usually only if I have been painted into a corner by existing code. If I have time/access/permission to change *upstream* code I will try to refactor to not need this. However, I have occasionally used this pattern in greenfield code, too.