# Gettitng error as Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a Stored procedure to Insert my data into the table,
but I am getting error as

> *Procedure or function 'AddUserDetails' expects parameter '@UserId', which was not supplied.*

Here is my SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddUserDetails 
@UserId nvarchar(55),
@UserPassword nvarchar(100),
@ConfirmPass nvarchar(100),
@Mobile int,
@Email nvarchar(100),
@BirthDate nvarchar(100)
AS  
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


     Insert into RegisterUser(UserId,UserPassword,ConfirmPass, Mobile, Email,BirthDate)Values (@UserId, @UserPassword, @ConfirmPass, @Mobile, @Email,@BirthDate)
END
GO
```

Also here is my C# code.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtUserId.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserPassword", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ConfirmPassword", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtConfirmPassword.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtMobile.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BirthDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtBirth.Text;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("AddUserDetails", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Kindly suggest what is the mistake here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are re-create your command with

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("AddUserDetails", con);
```

line and you *never* add any parameter to that cmd. You try to add old one with created `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();` line.

Delete this `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();` line and move your;

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddUserDetails", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

top of your code. That's it. And you never done anything in your catch part. Just throwed new exception with `throw ex;` but [this resets the stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex). And consider to use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections and commands automatically instead of calling `Close()` or `Dispose()` methods manually.

```
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddUserDetails", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtUserId.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserPassword", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ConfirmPassword", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtConfirmPassword.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtMobile.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BirthDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtBirth.Text;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // 
    }
```

Comment: @nadeem Just declare it as `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddUserDetails", con)`.

Comment: now getting error as `Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.`

Comment: @nadeem Since your `Mobile` column is `int`, you can's pass it this `txtMobile.Text` directly. Try to parse it to `int` first like `Convert.ToInt32(txtMobile.Text)` or something.

Comment: changed but getting error as `Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.`

Comment: @nadeem Then you need to change your column type that fits with your values. Read: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type