# Thrown exception is not visible on CATCH statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, exception, model-view-controller

I have problem with debuging code. I try to resolve one bug, but when I set breakpoint in catch statement and add watch to see details I get message from Visual Studio like below. Why? Can anyone explain me why is happens?

[image]

Comment: Are you starting the application in the debugger, running in Debug mode? Also, you can usually use `$exception` to get the current exception.

Comment: I set in web.config DEBUG to true and turn off code optimalization

Comment: You may want to read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex) given your use of `throw exc`.  If that's what you want, fair enough - just be aware of the difference...

Comment: When you step one further? It may do the declaration actually when it is used. Are you sure you have the current code in the debugger?

Comment: Is your project a Web Application project or a Web Site project?

Comment: In the IDE, the compilation configuration is "Debug" or "Release"?

Comment: Did you add exc just now or did you add it for a different method before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set "generate debug info" to "full" in the Compiler-settings

Answer (score 0):

This error frequently occurs if you declare a variable in a loop or a try or if block and then attempt to access it from an enclosing code block or a separate code block.

Comment: Can you see such a code block in OP's question? If exc is not visible there, I don't know...