# Catch exception not of a type

Tags: c#

Is there a difference when catching exceptions not of a type between :

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    throw;
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    ...
}
```

and :

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception exception) when (!(exception is TaskCanceledException))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: First one snippet will catch all exception with `TaskCanceledException` and in the second snippet will catch all  exception except  `TaskCanceledException`

Comment: Them can have different order of execution of `finally` clauses placed inside `try` block: https://tio.run/##7VI9T8MwEN3zK45OjgRRm5GIKWKDiUjMrnMlFsaubIdQVf7twalCPsBtQTByi3Pv5Z7vfI@ZK6Y0tm1tuHyCh52x@JJF0ywpKo209EBSUPNssmhbrwVnwAQ1BnLYR@CjB42l1h@vipdwT7kkcc93UaCxKxJnMyD9ANwxnb5sIsSlBQ43sByl1koJ2Mz@6iJX0iiByaPmFu@4RLI4yF3DfukWl8An3XSh0dZagtU1joQbvqzefbrAI7N8zoZrhjH8CKssSNlKqwYkNtA9ek4lQ4Hl7RvDreVKkvhrmYMNl1SIU7elgbLoeMaoZRWQYAvxubG7CbLz4oMg4HekRw3XKzQVSuI371ffsyedlP6tk9J/J/3ASaFlHxYI5IIMEHATbjb@vTNc274D

Comment: @PetSerAI interesting example, can you provide more reference to this behaviour, so in catch with filter the finally is executed at the last of all exception blocks? while in catch without filter, this is nested?

Comment: Both these methods are implemented differently in CLR (check the ILDASM) in the second one, first the when part is executed and on the basis of that the catch block will be entered. Have a look at: https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/c-6-0-exception-filter-and-when-keyword

Comment: @peeyushsingh System first search for a `catch` clause, which can handle exception. In doing so, system execute exception filters to check if `catch` is applicable. Only then nested `finally` clauses will be executed. It all in [specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/exceptions.md#how-exceptions-are-handled), although it is a bit outdated. Before exception filters became part of C#. Also, you can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/misc/securing-exception-handling).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, there is.

In the second block of code you are filtering on general exception type. It is not meant to be filtered, what happens if "TaskCanceledException" is thrown? you are not handling it and it will escalate to enclosing code. You are not really meant to filter anything on "Exception" type since it is the parent for all other type of exception and it is the last point of handling exception. A better option would be to create a custom exception and put them in separate block of catch and filter on them if needed.

The first option is more correct compared to the second one. Though you should not be throwing any exception and stay away from them, unless it is a complete deal breaker. On top of that what is the point of putting a catch block with Exception type bellow TaskCanceledException catch block which throws exception? You are basically telling that "I Would like to handle all exception" when using catch with Exception type, but at the same time you through one exception in exceptional case. Either throw the original exception or handle them.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: This answer doesn't make much sense and doesn't answer the question. Not sure why the OP marked it as accepted.

Comment: indeed, it's very opinionated, if you're filtering exceptions it's not unlikely that you actually want some of them to be passed to the calling code and only handle what's in direct control of that method

Comment: Re: "*Though you should not be throwing any exception and stay away from them*": This is a strong matter of opinion, and you're presenting it as established fact. You're more than welcome to use or not use Exceptions in any way you see fit, but [MS' official guidance on Exception throwing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/creating-and-throwing-exceptions) does not agree with your assertions here. In the general case, there are specific scenarios where you absolutely _should_ be throwing them (e.g. an argument is null which you expect to have a value).

Comment: I disagree with this, in my experience there is always a scenario how to handle a case instead of Throwing an exception. Exception are for exceptional cases, throwing them right and left pollutes your code and your logging system. If you know that the value is null by checking an if statement, it is in your control, thus deal with it.

Comment: @vsarunov I completely agree with you that Exceptions should be "exceptional"– that's kinda my entire point. To your credit, if you can handle the case, you probably shouldn't throw an exception– but if a method just _can't_ complete under a given condition (e.g. trying to get the total of items from a null collection), then that's precisely what exceptions are designed for. In my experience, when used well (and not excessively, like you mention), exceptions can be an amazing tool for both clean code and logs, and can give you invaluable insight into your system when something goes wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Refer to this link [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497774/catching-exceptions-with-catch-when)

Catch blocks already allow you to filter on the type of the exception:

```
catch (SomeSpecificExceptionType e) {...}
```

The when clause allows you to extend this filter to generic expressions.

Thus, you use the when clause for cases where the type of the exception is not distinct enough to determine whether the exception should be handled here or not.

Comment: This doesn't reply to the question

Answer (score -2):

The [Dixin's Blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/c-6-0-exception-filter-and-when-keyword) explained the difference with code example and VS screenshots.

> Exception filter does not unwind the stack, and catch block does unwind.  When executing catch block, this catch block’s method becomes the top frame of the stack. As a result, all the methods called by current method are removed from the stack. In contrast, exception filter can be helpful for runtime debugging. For example, if above Catch method is executed:

Comment: and what is a real life effect of that?