# C# "if exception is thrown..."

Tags: c#, exception, coding-style, conditional-statements

Not sure if this is *possible* or maybe considered *bad practice*, but I'm wondering if there's a *nice way* to write the above `if` statement in C#.

Something like...

```
if (method throws exception)
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: well best practice would be to have your code in a try catch statement. and do something like: ``` try { A = Method(); B = Method2(); } catch(Exception) { // Exception is thrown } ``` Everything which is in your try will continue execute except if one exception is thrown.

Comment: Still unclear. What is `method` here?

Comment: you can `catch` the exception (and `throw;` again if required): `try {... /* do something else */ } catch (Exception e) { /* If exception is thrown */ throw; }`

Comment: As well as the above comments, maybe give this a skim too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497774/catching-exceptions-with-catch-when

Comment: please check [try catch exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) documentation

Comment: Are you looking for `TryGet` pattern? https://ayoungdeveloper.com/post/2017-03-28-using-the-tryget-pattern-in-csharp/

Answer (score 1):

So what you are looking for is a try catch statement. This kind of structure is fairly common across many languages but for C# it's pretty wonderful.
I am going to refer you to Microsoft's documentation on the c# error handling.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch

This should teach you everything you need to know.
For a simple rundown on how it works in my terminology:

```
try {
//execute code that you expect to throw an exception
}
Catch (KindOfError ErrorVariable) {
//Error has been thrown, execute code for it.
msgbox.show("Error Raised: " + ErrorVariable.Code.ToString())
}
Finally {
//Execute code here you want to run regardless of error outcome
msgbox.show("This code runs with or without an exception being thrown")
}
```

This should help you out!

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of delegates and create some static helper.

You can use `Action` or `Func` in that case. Add another extension method which accepts `Func` if you need to return some value from executed function.

```
public static class SilentRunner
{
    public static void Run(Action action, Action<Exception> onErrorHandler)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            onErrorHandler(e);
        }
    }

    public static T Run<T>(Func<T> func, Action<Exception> onErrorHandler)
    {
        try
        {
            return func();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            onErrorHandler(e);
        }

        return default(T);
    }
}
```

And then use it so:

```
SilentRunner.Run(
     () => DoSomething(someObject),
     ex => DoSomethingElse(someObject, ex));
```

In case of `Func`, you can take result as well:

```
var result = SilentRunner.Run(
     () => DoSomething(someObject),
     ex => DoSomethingElse(someObject, ex));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use just a normal try-catch block. If the exception is thrown, it will go to the catch block, if not, it will continue executing the lines after the method that might throw an exception.

```
try
 {
 MethodThatMightThrowException()
 // do something else
 }
catch
 {
 // do something
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically can `catch` the exception:

```
 try { 
   var result = DoSomeAction(arguments);

   /* do something else : result is a valid value*/
 }
 catch (SomeException) {   //TODO: put the right exception type
   /* If exception is thrown; result is not valid */ 

   // throw; // uncomment, if you want to rethrow the exception
 }
```

However, you can implement `TryGet` *pattern* and have a *clear* `if`:

https://ayoungdeveloper.com/post/2017-03-28-using-the-tryget-pattern-in-csharp/

And use it as

```
 if (TryDoSomeAction(arguments, out var result)) {
   /* do something else : result is a valid value*/
 }
 else {
   /* result is not valid; if "exception" is thrown */ 
 }
```