# .NET Core ExecuteSqlRawAsync ignores execution strategy

Tags: asp.net-core, error-handling, dbcontext

I have a `DbContext` configured using `options.UseSqlServer()`.
I have a few dozen stored procedure calls defined in the DbContext. They all look something like this:

```
await Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("exec dbo.spDoMyVeryTailoredProcedure");
```

None of them arrive in the execution strategy `Execute` or `ExecuteAsync` methods. This prevents all errors produced in stored procedures from being handled by the execution strategy's resiliency logic and explicit logging instructions.

Is there a way to properly inject error handling into these SQL executions?

Comment: Have a look at [EF Core handling index violation best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71886960/ef-core-handling-index-violation-best-practices).