# Await call to web service is stopping the execution flow of the program

Tags: async-await, c#-5.0

I have the following code:

```
public async Task IntiateDataFetchingProcess(string[] args)
{
    try
    {           
        ProcessArgs(args);

        Log.Information("Run Mode: {RunModeID}", RunModeID);

        switch (RunModeID)
        {
            case RunModeType.A:
                await MethodAAsync();
                break;
            case RunModeType.B:
                await MethodBAsync();
                break;
            case RunModeType.C:
                TestMethod();
                break;
            default:                       
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                
        throw;
    }            
}

private async Task MethodBAsync()
{
   Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

   // Call to webservice to get the data
   var response = await _service.GetDataAsync(input1, request);

   Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());  
}
```

On debugging I found that the execution call comes to the below line (of method: `MethodBAsync`) and stops there.

```
var response = await _service.GetDataAsync(input1, request);
```

Can anyone help me to know is there anything that I am missing here.

Comment: What do you mean by "stops there"? Is the request never completing?

Comment: The execution of the code stops there. It is not moving to the next line.

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro, Check to see if you have any blocking method calls within that method ie `.Result`, `.Wait` etc...

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand what `async/await` do? `await` means `await`. It releases the current thread, *awaits* for it to finish, unpacks the result and resumes execution *after* the asynchronous call after it completes. It *doesn't* stop the execution of other threads.

Comment: To convince yourself, open the "Parallel Stacks" window from the Debug menu. You'll see that the method with `await` uses a different stack from the rest of the program.

Comment: Almost always, look for a call to `Result` or `Wait` not just in this method but higher up the "call stack" also. Almost always that's the root cause of the deadlock.

Comment: Here I am consuming a third party webservice using the proxy classes.I checked thoroughly for the call to Result or Wait and found no where they are used.

Comment: I am trying to call the above method from a console application. Will it make any difference there.

Comment: This is not about the central point of the question, but you should never use `throw ex;`. Use simply `throw;`, unless you don't want to deliberately erase the Exception stack trace. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex) for a wider discussion. I corrected it in my edit (visible soon)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, your code is getting deadlocked! 
You just need to add `.ConfigureAwait(false);` to each line that you are `await`ing.

Example:

`var response = await _service.GetDataAsync(input1, request);`

becomes

`var response = await _service.GetDataAsync(input1, 
request).ConfigureAwait(false);`

For more information on `.ConfigureAwait()`, Stephen Cleary wrote [an awesome post on it](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).