# Receiving an error when insert data into a .dbf file

Tags: c#, database, dbf, oledbconnection

**Backgournd**

I am currently working on a project which will need me to create a local `.dbf` file which I must then populate with a value. I am currently able to create a `.dbf` file in a test dir and adding a column to it, however when I later try to add a value to the column, it errors out.

**Problem**

I am currently not able to write to the column `Public` in the `.dbf` file which I created. When the code goes into `ExecuteNonQuery();`, it an error and is caught in my catch statement.

**Working code**

```
public static bool CreateDBF()
{
    try
    {
        string dbfDirectory = @"c:\Users\me\Desktop\New911";
        string connectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=" + dbfDirectory;
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "create table CustomProperties(Public C(60))";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            InsertDataIntoDBF(dbfDirectory + "\\CustomProperties.DBF");
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**Working Code** - appendix:

The above block of code successfully create the `.dbf` file with the column which I want as the following image will show

[image]

**Not working code:**

```
public static bool InsertDataIntoDBF(string path)
{
    try
    {
        string strLogConnectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=" + path + ";Collating Sequence=machine;Mode=ReadWrite;";
        string query = @"INSERT INTO CustomProperties (Public)";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(strLogConnectionString))
        {                    
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Public", "True");

            connection.Open();

            new OleDbCommand("set null off", connection).ExecuteNonQuery();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**Updated code blocks**

Working block:

```
public static bool CreateDBF()
{
  try
  {
    string dbfDirectory = @"c:\Users\er4505\Desktop\New911";
    string connectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=" + dbfDirectory;

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
      connection.Open();
      OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
      command.CommandText = "create table CustomProperties(Public C(60))";
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      connection.Close();
    }

    InsertDataIntoDBF(dbfDirectory + "\\CustomProperties.DBF");
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    string viewError = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex);
    return false; << I have a breakpoint here 
  }
}
```

Non-working block:

```
public static bool InsertDataIntoDBF(string path)
{
  try
  {
    string strLogConnectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=" + path + ";Collating Sequence=machine;Mode=ReadWrite;";
    string query = @"INSERT INTO CustomProperties (Public) VALUES (@Public)";
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(strLogConnectionString))
    {                    
      OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Public", "True");
      connection.Open();
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      connection.Close();
    }
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    string viewError = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex);
    return false; << breakpoint here 
  }
}
```

Error caught:

> oledbErrors
>   Message: Syntax error.
>   NativeError: 0
>   Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro
>
> ClassName: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
>   Message: Syntax error.

Comment: You are missing a part in the INSERT INTO statement. It should be _INSERT INTO CustomProperties (Public) VALUES (@Public)_

Comment: calling InsertDataIntoDBF() should be autside of the using block. You open connection two times- it may couses error

Comment: change 'throw' to 'throw ex' or use only 'catch(exception)' and then only 'throw'. Then you should see the error message

Comment: Your are right about opening the connection twice, thank you for the heads up.  However, the exception is. not coming in at all, i usually use log 4 net and it also shows nothing.

Comment: @Steve Thank you for the response to my question, I tried your code but it stills errors out.

Comment: What do you mean with errors out? Do you have now an error message? If you hit the exception the ex.Message will tell you something about the error and sometime also ex.InnerException.Message contains useful informations

Comment: Hey @Daniel, finally was able to read the error which it is giving me.  I updated the question which now has the error which I am getting when I am running ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was purely syntax, and I was guided by a really good example which I found in the following link

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24eac4c5-3a4d-43f4-8607-ef684919c4af/command-contains-unrecognized-phrasekeyword-vbnet?forum=visualfoxprogeneral

**Working Code Blocks**

```
public static bool CreateDBF()
{
  try
  {
    string dbfDirectory = @"c:\Users\er4505\Desktop\New911";
    string connectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=" + dbfDirectory;
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
      connection.Open();
      OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
      command.CommandText = "create table CustomProperties(Public C(60))";
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      connection.Close();
    }
    InsertDataIntoDBF(dbfDirectory + "\\CustomProperties.DBF");
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    string viewError = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex);
    return false;
  }
}

public static bool InsertDataIntoDBF(string path)
{
  try
  {
    string strLogConnectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=" + path + ";Collating Sequence=machine;Mode=ReadWrite;";
    string query = "INSERT INTO CustomProperties(Public) VALUES (?)";
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(strLogConnectionString))
    {
      connection.Open();
      OleDbCommand cmdInit = new OleDbCommand("set null off", connection);
      cmdInit.ExecuteNonQuery();
      OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
      OleDbParameter publicStatus = command.Parameters.Add("Public", OleDbType.Char);
      publicStatus.Value = "True";
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      connection.Close();
    }
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("EmailLogger").Error(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex));
            string viewError = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Try it

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            CreateDBF();
            Console.WriteLine(ReadDB());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static string dbfDirectory = @"c:\Test\dbTest";
    private static string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dbfDirectory + ";Extended Properties = dBase IV";
    public static bool CreateDBF()
    {            
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "Create Table CustomProperties ([Public] char(50))";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
        InsertDataIntoDBF(dbfDirectory + "\\CustomProperties.DBF");
        return true;
    }

    public static bool InsertDataIntoDBF(string path)
    {
        string query = @"INSERT INTO CustomProperties ([Public]) VALUES (@Public)";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Public", "True");
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static string ReadDB()
    {
        string res = string.Empty;
        string query = @"SELECT * FROM CustomProperties";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Public", "True");
            connection.Open();
            res = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
            connection.Close();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Nice I like the search block at the end.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static bool CreateDBF()
{
   ...
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            ...                
        }
        InsertDataIntoDBF(dbfDirectory + "\\CustomProperties.DBF"); // change 1
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw; //change2
    }
}

public static bool InsertDataIntoDBF(string path)
{
    try
    {
        ...       
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw; //change 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not _throw ex_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex

Comment: you're right, in this case better is not to reset the call stack. But if it would be a library for outside users then reset call stack is recommend. btw Thanks for comment.