# Return null if generic type is nullable

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, default-value, mysql-connector

I am writing a function that checks if an output is `DBNull` and returns null if the generic type is nullable. If not it simply throws the error.

**Update:** added all recommendations

```
public T Get<T>(string key)
{
    int ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal(key);
    if (reader.IsDBNull(ordinal))
    {
        if (typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) == null) // isn't a nullable field
            throw new InvalidCastException();
        else return default(T);
    }
    return reader.GetFieldValue<T>(ordinal);
}
```

However I am not sure if `default(T)` returns null for every nullable field. If now is there any other way to make it return null?

Comment: I'm not sure if `reader.GetFieldType(key)` would usually return `DBNull` - does that even work? I would *expect* that to return something that represents what the column would hold *if it weren't null*

Comment: Just as a suggestion (in addition to Marc's answer/comment), invert the `if` statement (if it's *not* null, `return ...;`), and do away with the `else`s for just a `throw...;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `default(T)` is the right kind of `null`-like value for every `T` that is actually a `SomeType?` / `Nullable<SomeType>`, so what you have should work fine.

You might want to consider things like `string` and `byte[]` though - these can *also* come from databases and can be null.

You might also want to think about what the error should be if someone simply makes a mistake and asks for `<int>` when the value is a `<decimal>`. That would cause `InvalidCastException`. There is an `IsDBNull()` method on `IDataReader` that might be more appropriate than using the exception.

Finally: prefer `throw;` to `throw e;`

Comment: [Is there a difference between “throw” and “throw ex”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/730255/209259).

Comment: @ShaiCohen I linked Marc's answer to that question in my comment.  It was for the OP not me :)

Answer (score 2):

In terms of computer resources, catching and handling an exception is an extremely expensive task. Your method is using the exception as part of its logic flow. This is an incorrect way of looking at the problem you are wanting to solve,.

In addition, you are catching specifically `InvalidCastException` exceptions. This exception can occur in other cases other than attempting to cast a null reference. You are hiding/misrepresenting a potentially valid error; something that can cost you many hours of frustrating, hair-pulling debugging.

The following should give you the same behavior as the original method, but without the overhead of unwinding the stack during the integrated error handling.

```
public T Get<T>(string key)
{
    if(reader.IsDbNull(reader.GetOrdinal(key)))
    {
       //IF YOU SPECIFICALLY WANT TO THROW AN ERROR IF A VALUE TYPE
       //if (typeof(T).IsValueType) 
       //{ throw new InvalidCastException(); }
       return default(T);
    }

    return reader.GetFieldValue<T>(reader.GetOrdinal(key));
}
```