# How to pass Exception Details from Chile to parent class(different Exception types)

Tags: c#, exception

I have below Child method which deal with DB calls. so this can produce normal exception or SQLexception also. so this code block have 2 catch blocks.

```
public void ChildMethod()
{
   try
   {
      //dbcall code
   }
   catch(Exception exc)
   {
      throw exc;
   }
   catch(sqlException sqlex)
   {
      throw sqlex;
   }
}
```

I have this Parent method which calls the Chile method. it have its own try  catch block. But how to pass the base exception, e.g. suppose there is a exception from child class, i want to pass the same exception to the parent methods catch block, thus i can push the exception details to some other source.

Parent code

```
public void ParentMethod()
{
try{
chileMethod();
}
catch(exception ex)
{
ApplicaitonInsightlogging.Add(ex); // This ex should contain the Base exception.
}
```

Comment: Adding throw only should work?

Comment: @Titi yes, just write "throw;" inside catch blocks of the child method.

Comment: OK great, thanks alot.

Comment: Still i have a query, In my child class i will have different type of exception. exception, sqlexception. But in my parent class only exception type will be there.
In case Sqlexception is thrown from child class will normal Exception in parent method will be able to handle it?

Comment: Please note exceptions are proceeded in the order you specify. So you need to change `Exception` and `SqlException` order. From MSDN: "Catch the more specific exceptions before the less specific ones. " (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch).

Comment: Regarding you question - yes, the parent `Exception` block will be able to catch all exception types, because  `Exception` is the parent for all of them.

Comment: Chile? is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Simply rethrow the exception from child

```
public void ChildMethod()
{
   try
   {
      //dbcall code
   }
   catch(Exception exc)
   {
     throw;
     //Or throw exc; 
   ...
```

*Notice that there is [difference between “throw” and “throw ex”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex)*