# c# Log4Net not logging the real line where exception happens

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a `c# controller` and inside a method I have code with a `try catch` statement:

My `controller` has a top level class attribute `LogAttribute`:

```
public class LogAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public ILogManager Logger { get; set; }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        Exception exception = filterContext.Exception;
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

        /* start log error */
        var logHelper = new Helpers.LogHelper (this.Logger);
        Guid errorUid = Guid.NewGuid();

        // call log4net
        logHelper.LogErrorString(errorUid, exception);
        /* end log error */
     }

}

[Log]
public class TestController 
{
   public JsonResult TestMethod(){

       try{

           //...some code here

           List<string> list = null;

           //Line 65 force expection Object reference not set to an instance of an object
           list.count(); 

       } 
       catch(Exception ex) {


           // ... do some code here

           throw ex; // Line 82
       }

      return null;
   }
}
```

The `Log4Net` logging is working fine but when I debug just after the `catch` and see the `Exception ex` I can see that the `StackTrace` line is the **65** as the exception line, and this is totally correct because is where the exception happened. But when `Log4Net` logs the error it shows as lines **82** that is exactly where I manually trhow the exception.

** UPDATE  **

> I just checked that the excepction `StackTrace` is correct in the `Catch` statement but exactly when the `MVC` Log attribute OnException handler catch that then the `stacktrace` is being reset. So is problem of the `OnException` method.
>
> Any clue?

Comment: read on `throw;` vs. `throw ex;` (probably can close as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex)

Comment: Just change that and issue still the same

Comment: I don't thing issue remains if you have `throw;` inside your `catch` block. Make sure you recompiled and restarted your application.

Comment: Make sure your other try catch blocks use throw as well. This inner try catch block is likely being overriden.

Comment: What I ended to is to throw a new exception passing as inner exception the actual one. And that solves the problem.