# Question about SQL connection and statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I currently have my SQL statements like this in my C# program.

```
        SqlConnection connection = DataBase.GetConnection();
        string deleteStatement = "DELETE FROM People WHERE ID = @ID";
        SqlCommand deleteCommand = new SqlCommand(deleteStatement, connection);
        deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Id);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
```

But visual studio 2019 is suggesting to use a using statement instead. Is there any benefit to using ether or?

Comment: it will handle the `finally` case for you automatically.

Comment: Why include the catch block here? What do you think it is providing you?

Comment: FYI: [Is there a difference between “throw” and “throw ex”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex)

Comment: I would think it providing an error to be thrown if the SQL server wasn't live any more. Because the SQL server is not running on the same computer as the application. The application connects to a remote SQL server..

Comment: Read the link @John provided. `throw ex` is far worse than not catching the exception at all.

Comment: Using block destroys the object automatically after scope goes out of iteration. For example if you use `using (SqlConnection connection = DataBase.GetConnection())`  then there is no need to write `connection.Close();` as using block automatically destroy the connection in end of scope even after any exceptions occurred.

Comment: Now is it good practice to do your using statement like you just did @Prakash Mhasavekar or use a variable like in Fabio post?

Comment: It's All upto you @Maverick. Both are valid. In many tutorials I have seen above method... Currently I'm also using this one.... Only difference is creating direct instance of SQL connection and storing it inside variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the accepted answer:

You could/should dispose `SqlCommand` as well and `using` will handle it.

```
using (var connection = DataBase.GetConnection())
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM People WHERE ID = @ID";
    var parameter = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@ID",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
        Value = Id
    };

    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: So what is the benefit to creating your parameter the way you wrote it to mine?

Comment: AddWithValue is considered to be bad practise - https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ - if you don’t specify what data type to use then it will be inferred, with potentially negative consequences

Answer (score 1):

`using` will automatically *dispose* of the connection (which also closes the connection).